# How to pass props to {this.props.children}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to find the proper way to define some components which could be used in a generic way:

```
<Parent>
  <Child value="1">
  <Child value="2">
</Parent>
```

There is a logic going on for rendering between parent and children components of course, you can imagine `<select>` and `<option>` as an example of this logic.

This is a dummy implementation for the purpose of the question:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  doSomething: function(value) {
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  onClick: function() {
    this.props.doSomething(this.props.value); // doSomething is undefined
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div onClick={this.onClick}></div>);
  }
});
```

The question is whenever you use `{this.props.children}` to define a wrapper component, how do you pass down some property to all its children?

Comment: I learned a lot from the answers to this question. I think the Context API is the best solution in today's React land. But if you want to use React.cloneElement, one gotcha I faced is not properly iterating the children with `React.Children.map()`. See more in [How To Pass Props to {react.children}](https://victorofoegbu.com/notes/pass-props-to-react-children-faq)

Answer (score 1489, accepted):

### Cloning children with new props

You can use [`React.Children`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children) to iterate over the children, and then clone each element with new props (shallow merged) using [`React.cloneElement`](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement).

See the code comment why I don't recommend this approach.

> Using cloneElement is uncommon and can lead to fragile code. See common alternatives.
> [source: react.dev](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement)

```js
const Child = ({ childName, sayHello }) => (
  <button onClick={() => sayHello(childName)}>{childName}</button>
);

function Parent({ children }) {
  // We pass this `sayHello` function into the child elements.
  function sayHello(childName) {
    console.log(`Hello from ${childName} the child`);
  }

  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child => {
    // Checking isValidElement is the safe way and avoids a
    // typescript error too.
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { sayHello });
    }
    return child;
  });

  return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
}

function App() {
  // This approach is less type-safe and Typescript friendly since it
  // looks like you're trying to render `Child` without `sayHello`.
  // It's also confusing to readers of this code.
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child childName="Billy" />
      <Child childName="Bob" />
    </Parent>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

### Calling children as a function

Alternatively, you can pass props to children via [render props](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#alternatives). In this approach, the children (which can be `children` or any other prop name) is a function which can accept any arguments you want to pass and returns the actual children:

```js
const Child = ({ childName, sayHello }) => (
  <button onClick={() => sayHello(childName)}>{childName}</button>
);

function Parent({ children }) {
  function sayHello(childName) {
    console.log(`Hello from ${childName} the child`);
  }

  // `children` of Parent must be a function
  // which returns the actual children. We can pass
  // it args to then pass into them as props (in this
  // case we pass `sayHello`).
  return <div>{children(sayHello)}</div>
}

function App() {
  // sayHello is the arg we passed in Parent, which
  // we now pass through to Child.
  return (
    <Parent>
      {(sayHello) => (
        <>
          <Child childName="Billy" sayHello={sayHello} />
          <Child childName="Bob" sayHello={sayHello} />
        </>
      )}
    </Parent>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. this is not defined within React.cloneElement()

Comment: @Patrick what's not defined? Did you look at the working Fiddle?

Comment: This works great for passing down properties but when I pass down a function with a callback the callback object doesn't return.  Am I doing something wrong or should I be doing something different for this case?

Comment: @conor909 can you send me a pastebin example of what you're doing?

Comment: @DominicTobias sorry about the late reply I'v been away.  Here is a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/conor909/gqdfwg6p/

Comment: @conor909 Np, why are you using context to call myFunction - `this.context.myFunction`. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do without a working example but you should be calling `this.props.myFunction` from the child - context is unecessary

Comment: @DominicTobias Thanks for your input and apologies I didnt update the context / props in my jsFiddle. I meant to use `props`.  I'v updated it now.  I'v also asked this question on SO, if you'd like to contribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520479/how-to-use-react-cloneelement-to-pass-a-function-property-with-a-return-object?noredirect=1#comment60646975_36520479

Comment: I am trying to understand in what different situations why you would want to use this.props.children? In this answer, it looks like you gain the ability to catch the children before render from within the parent's definition and do things to the children before returning them for render. Also the docs mention the React.children methods which I don't see the use for. The docs use cases don't seem intuitive to me and they don't only give the example of passing them down, which could literally be done everywhere in the app without regards to sanity or reason.

Comment: This answer doesn't work, the `value` passed to `doSomething` is lost.

Comment: @DominicTobias Arg, sorry, I switched console.log to alert and forgot to concat the two params to a single string.

Comment: When there's only 1 single child element is `this.props.children` meant to be a singleton and not an array? Because I found that when there's only 1 single child element, I could just use `React.cloneElement(this.props.children, ...)`.

Comment: what if i have non react elements in `this.props.children` like `<div> / </br>` etc.???

Comment: This answer was super-helpful, but I ran into an issue that isn't mentioned here and I was wondering if it's some new thing that's changed or whether it's something odd on my end.  When I cloned my child element, it's child was set to the old element, until I added this.props.children.props.children to the third argument of cloneElement.

Comment: What if the child is loaded via a route (v4) thats loaded from a separate route page?

Comment: Check your children type if you get "element type invalid" error. This threw me down a well of 2 hours of debugging, because my children object occasionally alternated between a string - from way up in the app - and a normal array-like structure. When you clone a string it doesn't yell at you, it creates an invalid react element.

Comment: Why is it necessary/better/safer to clone the component instead of mutating it? I've asked this question in more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54825692/1720199).

Comment: downvote reason:  in your sample - promoting bad practices and low quality code to readers, a dieu spagetti guy

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi I'm demonstrating a a technical answer not architecting something. I would tend to use renderprops over cloneElement. How do you suggest it should be different?

Comment: @Marwen Trabelsi what would be considered best practice?

Comment: stop using arrow fn everywhere - debugger will not catch them! - only when it makes sense

Comment: Not related to the question, but there's no sense of using PureComponent, when it has children passed in the props, as it won't skip any updates.

Comment: Sorry, it was first answer `Calling children as a function` pattern

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54534202/10828885

Could you please remind about it?

Comment: Can't get this to work with typescript

Comment: This got me on the right track with TypeScripting this, like `<Parent injector={(addedProps:InjectedProps) => (<> <MyComponent {...addedProps} value={1}/> <MyComponent {...addedProps} value={2}/> </>)}/>`. Now `MyComponent` can have the props in `InjectedProps` as mandatory, instead of making them optional and relying on `cloneElement` to add them. @ANimator120 perhaps this helps you too?

Comment: In TS, using `children` as a function requires checking typeof function, and then TS still can't check if it passes `InjectedProps` to it. Instead, a new prop like `injector` can be strongly typed in `Parent` as a `Function<InjectedProps,ReactNode>` so it _can_ check both the parameters it passes to `injector`, *and* the `injector` passed to this `Parent` by some ancestor.

Comment: My favourite is the "render props" variant, as it's the simplest (shortest code), just wraps the component inside a function (which is what you do anyway) and allows you to pass anything as you wish. No contexts, no nothing extra.

Comment: I am still clueless on how to refactor this to TS:  {({ value }) => this.props.children(value)}

Comment: It says no constituent of type React node is callable

Comment: "Calling children as a function" --> Is btw. the same principle as *open recursion* from object orientation.

Answer (score 557):

For a slightly cleaner way to do it, try:

```
<div>
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { loggedIn: this.state.loggedIn })}
</div>
```

Edit:
To use with multiple individual children (the child must itself be a component) you can do. Tested in 16.8.6

```
<div>
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children[0], { loggedIn: true, testPropB: true })}
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children[1], { loggedIn: true, testPropA: false })}
</div>
```

Comment: Could someone explain how this works (or what it actually does)?  Reading [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement), I couldn't see how this would descend into the children and add that prop to each child - is that what it is intended to do?  If it does, how do we know that this is what it will do?   It's not at all obvious that it's even valid to pass an opaque data structure (`this.props.children`) to `cloneElement` ... which is expecting an ... element.

Comment: Exactly, this doesn't seem to work with more than one children.

Comment: Yeah I was surprised that this worked for people, I would have thought it'd throw an error actually

Comment: It works because `this.props.children` is just a React component when there is only one child: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html

Comment: So you can write code that works while someone passes only one child into a component, but when they add another, it crashes ... that doesn't sound great on face value?    It would seem to be a trap for the OP, who asked specifically about passing props to _all_ children.

Comment: @GreenAsJade its fine as long as your component is expecting a single child. You can define via your components propTypes that it expects a single child. `React.Children.only` function returns the only child or throws an exception if there are multiple (this wouldn't exist if there wasn't a use case).

Comment: @Danita If this isn't working for you and you're running into an error, for example: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null` try updating your code to `{this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { loggedIn: this.state.loggedIn })}` This checks for the existence of children first and only executes `cloneElement` if children exist.

Comment: What if I need to add `ref` prop?

Comment: This method should be combined with proptypes that specifiy that only a single `child` is allowed / required: `myComponent.propTypes = { children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired }`. As defined here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#requiring-single-child . `PropTypes.node` specify one or more children, where as `PropTypes.element` specifies exactly 1 element.

Comment: Downvoted. It does not answer the question "How do I pass down some property to _all_ children?". It does not even mention the fact that it will crash and burn if you attempt to use it for more than one child. How did 173 people think that this was a good answer?

Comment: Downvoted for the same reason @Søren Boisen mentioned. At least edit your answer and include the fact that you have to make sure there is only on child element in your props by e.g. checking it in `propTypes`.

Comment: will doing this slow down render ?

Comment: This answer very clearly demonstrates why it was a bad decision by the React team to have `this.props.children` (note the plural!) be the single object itself when there is only one child. It means you can never treat `this.props.children` as a normal array, because it might actually not be an array. Hence all the helpers to deal with children. In Preact they chose to simply always use an array and it makes life so much easier. Also, with ES6, having functions like `cloneElement` to just make a shallow copy are overkill: `var copy = { ... original }` is all you need.

Comment: `React.Children.toArray()` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray

Comment: For the love of god, I can't get this to work! I set `{myProp: () => console.log("damn prop")}`, been trying this and other answers for hours now and none works ;/ . If I log the `children` I can see it set, but over on the child's component and it not there. Bah.

Comment: Reacts does not have `cloneElements`? Adding a wrapper would do?

Comment: React.children is an opaque data structure.  You certainly should not be accessing it as if it were an array: that edit to the answer is plain wrong.   As @MarkSwardstrom said some time back, you need to use toArray()

Answer (score 129):

Try this

```
<div>{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props})}</div>
```

It worked for me using react-15.1.

Use  `{...this.props}`  is suggested in https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Comment: Is it possible to return `React.cloneElement()` directly without surrounding it in `<div>` tags? Because what if the child is a `<span>` (or something else) and we want to preserve its tag element type?

Comment: If it's one child you can leave out the wrapper and this solution only works for one child so yes.

Comment: Works for me. Without enclosing <div> is ok.

Comment: If you need to explicitly enforce that you only receive one child, you can do `React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(this.props.children), {...this.props})` which will throw an error if it is passed more than one child. Then you don't need to wrap in a div.

Comment: @adrianmc now you can use <React.Fragment> instead of a div

Comment: This answer may produce a TypeError: cyclic object value. Unless you want one of the child's props to be itself, use `let {children, ...acyclicalProps} = this.props` and then `React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children), acyclicalProps)`.

Comment: can this be used with functional component? `{React.cloneElement(props.children, { ...props })}` doesnt seem to work

Comment: `No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'`

Answer (score 109):

### Pass props to direct children.

See all other answers

### Pass shared, global data through the component tree via [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html)

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language. <sup>1</sup>

*Disclaimer: This is an updated answer, the previous one used the old context API*

It is based on Consumer / Provide principle. First, create your context

```
const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext(defaultValue);
```

Then use via

```
<Provider value={/* some value */}>
  {children} /* potential consumers */
</Provider>
```

and

```
<Consumer>
  {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
</Consumer>
```

> All Consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes. **The propagation from Provider to its descendant Consumers is not subject to the shouldComponentUpdate method, so the Consumer is updated even when an ancestor component bails out of the update.**  <sup>1</sup>

Full example, semi-pseudo code.

```
import React from 'react';

const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext({ color: 'white' });

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: { color: 'black' },
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider value={this.state.value}>
        <Toolbar />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

class Toolbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <p> Consumer can be arbitrary levels deep </p>
        <Consumer> 
          {value => <p> The toolbar will be in color {value.color} </p>}
        </Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer this will work properly even when there are other elements included under Parent. This is definitely the best answer.

Comment: Props != context

Comment: you cannot depend on changes propagating through context. Use props when it's possible they change.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but isn't it wrong to say "context makes props available"? When I last used context, it was a separate thing (i.e. `this.context`)--it didn't magically merge the context with props. You had to intentionally set and use the context, which is a whole other thing.

Comment: You understand perfectly, it was incorrect. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @ThaJay no, but you can pass a `subscribeToX` function down through context and call it in descendants to subscribe to changes to X.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I don't think using `context` is ever truly the only option.  Better to be encouraging than discouraging -- I would say "context can be extremely convenient -- just learn enough about it to know the pitfalls and when not to use it."

Comment: @ThaJay also, react-router v4 does actually (somewhat controversially) rely on passing changing props down through context.  There are explicit instructions in their docs about how to prevent pure components from swallowing the prop changes by wrapping them in `withRouter`.

Comment: @Andy not the same, but it does work indeed. The function is static and defined only once. Check out MobX for a good example that follows this line of thought (mutable redux alternative).

Comment: @ThaJay I'm aware of MobX but don't know anything about how it uses context, do you have a link maybe?

Comment: I have to edit this answer, because they have a new context API, but writing my thesis currently. Soon :-)

Comment: @Andy from the writer of MobX himself
https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-safely-use-react-context-b7e343eff076

Comment: For function component, we could use `useContext` instead of `<Consumer>`. Also new doc link: https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

Answer (score 78):

### Passing Props to Nested Children

With the update to React Hooks you can now use **React.createContext** and **useContext**.

```
import * as React from 'react';

// React.createContext accepts a defaultValue as the first param
const MyContext = React.createContext(); 

functional Parent(props) {
  const doSomething = React.useCallback((childName) => {
    // Do something here with value
  }, []);

  return (
     <MyContext.Provider value={{ doSomething }}>
       {props.children}
     </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
 
function Child(props: { childName: string }) {
  const myContext = React.useContext(MyContext);

  const onClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    myContext.doSomething(props.childName);
  }, [props.childName, myContext.doSomething]);

  return (
    <div onClick={onClick}>{props.childName}</div>
  );
}
```

---

```
// Example of using Parent and Child

import * as React from 'react';

function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child childName="Billy" />
      <Child childName="Bob" />
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

**React.createContext** shines where **React.cloneElement** case couldn't handle nested components

```
function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child childName="Billy" />
      <SomeOtherComp>
        <Child childName="Bob" />
      </SomeOtherComp>
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why => functions are a bad practice? The => function helps bind the event handlers to get `this` context

Comment: @KennethTruong because each time it renders it creates a function.

Comment: @itdoesntwork that's not true. It only creates a new function when the class is created. Its not being created during the render function..

Comment: @KennethTruong https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render i thought you were talking about arrow function in render.

Comment: I would remove `value={2}` in your code. Reason: 1) It's not necessary for explaining the context. 2) It distracts for the actual key point of the code, which is the use of `myContext`. :)

Answer (score 52):

The best way, which allows you to make property transfer is `children` like a function pattern
https://medium.com/merrickchristensen/function-as-child-components-5f3920a9ace9

Code snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fcmubc

Example:

```js
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
    const somePropsHere = {
      style: {
        color: "red"
      }
      // any other props here...
    }
    return children(somePropsHere)
}

const ChildComponent = props => <h1 {...props}>Hello world!</h1>

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Parent>
      {props => (
        <ChildComponent {...props}>
          Bla-bla-bla
        </ChildComponent>
      )}
    </Parent>
  )
}
```

Comment: This seems way more straightforward (and better for performance?) to me than the accepted answer.

Comment: This requires children to be a function and does not work for deply nested components

Comment: @digitalillusion, I don't understand what does it mean `nested components`.
React doesn't have nested patterns, only compositions.
Yes, children must be a function, there is no any conflicts, because this's valid JSX child. 
Can you give an example with `nesting components` ?

Comment: You are right the case of deeply nested children can be handled as well `<Parent>{props => <Nest><ChildComponent /></Nest>}</Parent>` instead of (not working) `<Parent><Nest>{props => <ChildComponent />}</Nest></Parent>` so I agree this is the best answer

Comment: When attempting, I receive the following: `TypeError: children is not a function`

Comment: @RyanPrentiss I could look on your code. Can you share any snippet?

Comment: @RyanPrentiss I get the same error, did you figure it out?

Comment: @ekkis code snippet, probably it could help
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fcmubc

Answer (score 36):

You can use `React.cloneElement`, it's better to know how it works before you start using it in your app. It's introduced in `React v0.13`, read on for more information, so something along with this work for you:

```
<div>{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props})}</div>
```

So bring the lines from React documentation for you to understand how it's all working and how you can make use of them:

> In React v0.13 RC2 we will introduce a new API, similar to
> React.addons.cloneWithProps, with this signature:

```
React.cloneElement(element, props, ...children);
```

> Unlike cloneWithProps, this new function does not have any magic
> built-in behavior for merging style and className for the same reason
> we don't have that feature from transferPropsTo. Nobody is sure what
> exactly the complete list of magic things are, which makes it
> difficult to reason about the code and difficult to reuse when style
> has a different signature (e.g. in the upcoming React Native).
>
> React.cloneElement is almost equivalent to:

```
<element.type {...element.props} {...props}>{children}</element.type>
```

> However, unlike JSX and cloneWithProps, it also preserves refs. This
> means that if you get a child with a ref on it, you won't accidentally
> steal it from your ancestor. You will get the same ref attached to
> your new element.
>
> One common pattern is to map over your children and add a new prop.
> There were many issues reported about cloneWithProps losing the ref,
> making it harder to reason about your code. Now following the same
> pattern with cloneElement will work as expected. For example:

```
var newChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
  return React.cloneElement(child, { foo: true })
});
```

> Note: React.cloneElement(child, { ref: 'newRef' }) DOES override the
> ref so it is still not possible for two parents to have a ref to the
> same child, unless you use callback-refs.
>
> This was a critical feature to get into React 0.13 since props are now
> immutable. The upgrade path is often to clone the element, but by
> doing so you might lose the ref. Therefore, we needed a nicer upgrade
> path here. As we were upgrading callsites at Facebook we realized that
> we needed this method. We got the same feedback from the community.
> Therefore we decided to make another RC before the final release to
> make sure we get this in.
>
> We plan to eventually deprecate React.addons.cloneWithProps. We're not
> doing it yet, but this is a good opportunity to start thinking about
> your own uses and consider using React.cloneElement instead. We'll be
> sure to ship a release with deprecation notices before we actually
> remove it so no immediate action is necessary.

more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/03/react-v0.13-rc2.html)...

Answer (score 14):

#### Method 1 - clone children

```
const Parent = (props) => {
   const attributeToAddOrReplace= "Some Value"
   const childrenWithAdjustedProps = React.Children.map(props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { attributeToAddOrReplace})
   );

   return <div>{childrenWithAdjustedProps }</div>
}
```

[Full Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-te35fc?file=src/App.js)

#### Method 2 - use composable context

Context allows you to pass a prop to a deep child component without explicitly passing it as a prop through the components in between.

Context comes with drawbacks:

1. Data doesn't flow in the regular way - via props.
2. Using context creates a contract between the consumer and the provider. It might be more difficult to understand and replicate the requirements needed to reuse a component.

**Using a composable context**

```
export const Context = createContext<any>(null);

export const ComposableContext = ({ children, ...otherProps }:{children:ReactNode, [x:string]:any}) => {
    const context = useContext(Context)
    return(
      <Context.Provider {...context} value={{...context, ...otherProps}}>{children}</Context.Provider>
    );
}

function App() {
  return (
      <Provider1>
            <Provider2> 
                <Displayer />
            </Provider2>
      </Provider1>
  );
}

const Provider1 =({children}:{children:ReactNode}) => (
    <ComposableContext greeting="Hello">{children}</ComposableContext>
)

const Provider2 =({children}:{children:ReactNode}) => (
    <ComposableContext name="world">{children}</ComposableContext>
)

const Displayer = () => {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  return <div>{context.greeting}, {context.name}</div>;
};
```

Comment: A bit late, but could you explain the notation in `{children}:{children:ReactNode}`?

Comment: @camille, It's a Typescript thing. Looking at it now, I would just answer with Javascript, and even if I would write Typescript, I'd do it differently. Might edit it in the future.

Comment: @camille, basically it means that the value which has the key `"children"` is of type `ReactNode`

Comment: @Ben Carp by using method 1 how can I access `attributeToAddOrReplace ` this into children file ?

Comment: Hi @SamikshaJagtap, I added a demo to more clearly show how it is done. Hope this helps! https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-te35fc?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 13):

I needed to fix accepted answer above to make it work using **that** instead of **this** pointer. **This** within the scope of map function didn't have **doSomething** function defined.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
doSomething: function() {
    console.log('doSomething!');
},

render: function() {
    var that = this;
    var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { doSomething: that.doSomething });
    });

    return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
}})
```

Update: this fix is for ECMAScript 5, in ES6 there is no need in **var that=this**

Comment: or just use `bind()`

Comment: or use an arrow function which binds to lexical scope, I updated my answer

Comment: what if `doSomething` took an object, like `doSomething: function(obj) { console.log(obj) }` and in the Child you'd call `this.props.doSomething(obj)` to log out `"obj"`

Comment: @plus- i know this is old, but using bind here is a terrible idea, bind creates a new function that binds the context to a new one. basically a function calling the `apply` method. using `bind()` in the render function will create a new function each time the render method is called.

Answer (score 11):

None of the answers address the issue of having children that are **NOT** React components, such as text strings. A workaround could be something like this:

```
// Render method of Parent component
render(){
    let props = {
        setAlert : () => {alert("It works")}
    };
    let childrenWithProps = React.Children.map( this.props.children, function(child) {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)){
            return React.cloneElement(child, props);
        }
          return child;
      });
    return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Cleaner way considering one or more children

```
<div>
   { React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, {...this.props}))}
</div>
```

Comment: This one doesn't work for me, it gives an error: children not defined.

Comment: @Deelux this.props.children instead of children

Comment: this passes the child as its own children in `this.props`.  In general I'd only recommend cloning with specific props, not the whole shebang.

Comment: Passing `{...this.props}` didn't work for me, is the way `{...child.props}` correct?

Comment: For functional components: `React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, props))`

Comment: For conditional routes, you may need to check for null: `React.Children.map(children, (child) => child ? React.cloneElement(child, props) : null)`

Answer (score 8):

If you have multiple children you want to [pass props](https://kolosek.com/react-props-basic) to, you can do it this way, using the React.Children.map:

```
render() {
    let updatedChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
        (child) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, { newProp: newProp });
        });

    return (
        <div>
            { updatedChildren }
        </div>
    );
}
```

If your component is having just one child, there's no need for mapping, you can just cloneElement straight away:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                    newProp: newProp
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Parent.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

const doSomething = value => {};

const Parent = props => (
  <div>
    {
      !props || !props.children 
        ? <div>Loading... (required at least one child)</div>
        : !props.children.length 
            ? <props.children.type {...props.children.props} doSomething={doSomething} {...props}>{props.children}</props.children.type>
            : props.children.map((child, key) => 
              React.cloneElement(child, {...props, key, doSomething}))
    }
  </div>
);
```

Child.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

/* but better import doSomething right here,
   or use some flux store (for example redux library) */
export default ({ doSomething, value }) => (
  <div onClick={() => doSomething(value)}/>
);
```

and main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Parent from './Parent';
import Child from './Child';

render(
  <Parent>
    <Child/>
    <Child value='1'/>
    <Child value='2'/>
  </Parent>,
  document.getElementById('...')
);
```

see example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/jJHQECrKRrtKlKYRpIWl?p=preview

Answer (score 7):

Got inspired by all the answers above and this is what I have done. I am passing some props like some data, and some components.

```
import React from "react";

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const { setCheckoutData } = actions.shop;
  const { Input, FieldError } = libraries.theme.components.forms;

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    setCheckoutData(data);
  };

  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(
    children,
    (child) =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        Input: Input,
        FieldError: FieldError,
        onSubmit: onSubmit,
      })
  );

  return <>{childrenWithProps}</>;
};
```

Comment: it's useless to write `<>{childrenWithProps}</>` since `childrenWithProps` is already an Array. Return `childrenWithProps` is suffice. BTW, this answer is identical to the selected one from 6 years ago - both use `React.Children.map` and then `cloneElement`

Answer (score 6):

Here's my version that works with single, multiple, and invalid children.

```
const addPropsToChildren = (children, props) => {
  const addPropsToChild = (child, props) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, props);
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid element: ", child);
      return child;
    }
  };
  if (Array.isArray(children)) {
    return children.map((child, ix) =>
      addPropsToChild(child, { key: ix, ...props })
    );
  } else {
    return addPropsToChild(children, props);
  }
};
```

Usage example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mcclintock-59emq?file=/src/ChildVsChildren.jsx:0-1069

Answer (score 5):

Further to @and_rest answer, this is how I clone the children and add a class.

```
<div className="parent">
    {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, {className:'child'}))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can also find useful this feature, though many people have considered this as an anti-pattern it still can be used if you're know what you're doing and design your solution well.

[Function as Child Components](https://medium.com/merrickchristensen/function-as-child-components-5f3920a9ace9)

Answer (score 5):

I think a render prop is the appropriate way to handle this scenario

You let the Parent provide the necessary props used in child component, by refactoring the Parent code to look to something like this:

```
const Parent = ({children}) => {
  const doSomething(value) => {}

  return children({ doSomething })
}
```

Then in the child Component you can access the function provided by the parent this way:

```
class Child extends React {

  onClick() => { this.props.doSomething }

  render() { 
    return (<div onClick={this.onClick}></div>);
  }

}
```

Now the fianl stucture will look like this:

```
<Parent>
  {(doSomething) =>
   (<Fragment>
     <Child value="1" doSomething={doSomething}>
     <Child value="2" doSomething={doSomething}>
    <Fragment />
   )}
</Parent>
```

Comment: what if the parent is just a wrapper for a {children} that is a textarea in another class component?

Answer (score 3):

The slickest way to do this:

```
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
```

Comment: Does this not copy this.props.children into this.props.children of the child? and in effect copying the child into itself?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of `cloneElement()`

```
React.cloneElement(
  element,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

> Clone and return a new React element using element as the starting
>   point. The resulting element will have the original element’s props
>   with the new props merged in shallowly. New children will replace
>   existing children. key and ref from the original element will be
>   preserved.
>
> `React.cloneElement()` is almost equivalent to:
>
> ```
> <element.type {...element.props} {...props}>{children}</element.type>
> ```
>
> However, it also preserves refs. This means that if you get a child
>   with a ref on it, you won’t accidentally steal it from your ancestor.
>   You will get the same ref attached to your new element.

So cloneElement is what you would use to provide custom props to the children. However there can be multiple children in the component and you would need to loop over it. What other answers suggest is for you to map over them using `React.Children.map`. However `React.Children.map` unlike `React.cloneElement` changes the keys of the Element appending and extra `.$` as the prefix. Check this question for more details: [React.cloneElement inside React.Children.map is causing element keys to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028558/react-cloneelement-inside-react-children-map-is-causing-element-keys-to-change/47030407#47030407)

If you wish to avoid it, you should instead go for the `forEach` function like

```
render() {
    const newElements = [];
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, 
              child => newElements.push(
                 React.cloneElement(
                   child, 
                   {...this.props, ...customProps}
                )
              )
    )
    return (
        <div>{newElements}</div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For any one who has a single child element this should do it.

```
{React.isValidElement(this.props.children)
                  ? React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                      ...prop_you_want_to_pass
                    })
                  : null}
```

Answer (score 2):

You no longer need `{this.props.children}`. Now you can wrap your child component using `render` in `Route` and pass your props as usual:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/posts">Posts</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
    </ul>

    <hr/>

    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/posts" render={() => (
      <Posts
        value1={1}
        value2={2}
        data={this.state.data}
      />
    )} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Render props are now standard in React (https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) and are worth considering as a new accepted answer for this question.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: Yeah... this doesn't answer the question because the question isn't about react-router.  It did, however, answer my question related to this question that is specific to react-router.  This basic info is not clear anywhere on react-router's website that I can find.  Certainly not mentioned in their upgrade notes (which are terribly incomplete).  This answer should be moved to its own question.

Answer (score 2):

When using functional components, you will often get the `TypeError: Cannot add property myNewProp, object is not extensible` error when trying to set new properties on `props.children`. There is a work around to this by cloning the props and then cloning the child itself with the new props.

```js
const MyParentComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='whatever'>
      {props.children.map((child) => {
        const newProps = { ...child.props }
        // set new props here on newProps
        newProps.myNewProp = 'something'
        const preparedChild = { ...child, props: newProps }
        return preparedChild
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came to this post while researching for a similar need, but i felt cloning solution that is so popular, to be too raw and takes my focus away from the functionality.

I found an article in react documents [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Here is my sample:

```
import React from 'react';

const withForm = (ViewComponent) => {
    return (props) => {

        const myParam = "Custom param";

        return (
            <>
                <div style={{border:"2px solid black", margin:"10px"}}>
                    <div>this is poc form</div>
                    <div>
                        <ViewComponent myParam={myParam} {...props}></ViewComponent>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default withForm;


const pocQuickView = (props) => {
    return (
        <div style={{border:"1px solid grey"}}>
            <div>this is poc quick view and it is meant to show when mouse hovers over a link</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withForm(pocQuickView);
```

For me i found a flexible solution in implementing the pattern of Higher Order Components.

Of course it depends on the functionality, but it is good if someone else is looking for a similar requirement, it is much better than being dependent on raw level react code like cloning.

Other pattern that i actively use is the container pattern. do read about it, there are many articles out there.

Answer (score 2):

In my case **React.cloneElement()** was giving me to many problems and I'm using functional components with Typescript so I used **children(props)** as a way to pass my props to my children element. Again my case was very unique where I had to pass the parent component an attribute then based on that attribute it will pass in certain props to the children components. This can be seen in a simple example here [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-bell-twqo1u?file=/src/Parent.tsx)

***App.tsx***

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Parent from "./Parent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Parent title={"With div wrapper"}>
        {({ title }) => <h1>{title}</h1>}
      </Parent>

      <Parent>
        {({ title }) => <h1>{title === undefined && "this is undefined"}</h1>}
      </Parent>
    </>
  );
}
```

***Parent.tsx***

```js
export interface ChildrenProps {
  title?: string;
}

interface ParentWrapperProps {
  children: (title: ChildrenProps) => JSX.Element;
  title?: string;
}

const ParentWrapper: React.FC<ParentWrapperProps> = ({ children, title }) => {
  return title ? (
    <div>{children({ title: title })}</div>
  ) : (
    <>{children({ title: undefined })}</>
  );
};

export default ParentWrapper;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you required?

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  doSomething: function(value) {
  }
  render: function() {
    return  <div>
              <Child doSome={this.doSomething} />
            </div>
  }
})

var Child = React.createClass({
  onClick:function() {
    this.props.doSome(value); // doSomething is undefined
  },  
  render: function() {
    return  <div onClick={this.onClick}></div>
  }
})
```

Comment: Nope, I don't want to constraint the content of my wrapper to some specific content.

Answer (score 1):

I did struggle to have the listed answers work but failed. Eventually, I found out that the issue is with correctly setting up the parent-child relationship. Merely nesting components inside other components does not mean that there is a parent-child relationship.

Example 1. Parent-child relationship;

```
function Wrapper() {
  return (
    <div>
      <OuterComponent>
        <InnerComponent />
      </OuterComponent>
    </div>
  );
}
function OuterComponent(props) {
  return props.children;
}
function InnerComponent() {
  return <div>Hi! I'm in inner component!</div>;
}
export default Wrapper;
```

Example 2. Nested components:

```
function Wrapper() {
  return (
    <div>
      <OuterComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
function OuterComponent(props) {
  return <InnerComponent />
}
function InnerComponent() {
  return <div>Hi! I'm in inner component!</div>;
}
export default Wrapper;
```

As I said above, props passing works in Example 1 case.

The article below explains it https://medium.com/@justynazet/passing-props-to-props-children-using-react-cloneelement-and-render-props-pattern-896da70b24f6

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering how to do this properly in TypeScript where there are one or multiple child nodes. I am using the [uuid](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) library to generate unique key attributes for the child elements which, of course, you don't need if you're only cloning one element.

```
export type TParentGroup = {
  value?: string;
  children: React.ReactElement[] | React.ReactElement;
};

export const Parent = ({
  value = '',
  children,
}: TParentGroup): React.ReactElement => (
  <div className={styles.ParentGroup}>
    {Array.isArray(children)
      ? children.map((child) =>
          React.cloneElement(child, { key: uuidv4(), value })
        )
      : React.cloneElement(children, { value })}
  </div>
);
```

As you can see, this solution takes care of rendering an array of or a single `ReactElement`, and even allows you to pass properties down to the child component(s) as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Some reason React.children was not working for me. This is what worked for me.

I wanted to just add a class to the child. similar to changing a prop

```
 var newChildren = this.props.children.map((child) => {
 const className = "MenuTooltip-item " + child.props.className;
    return React.cloneElement(child, { className });
 });

 return <div>{newChildren}</div>;
```

The trick here is the [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement). You can pass any prop in a similar manner

Answer (score 0):

[Render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) is most accurate approach to this problem. Instead of passing the child component to parent component as children props, let parent render child component manually. *Render* is built-in props in react, which takes function parameter. In this function you can let parent component render whatever you want with custom parameters. Basically it does the same thing as child props but it is more customizable.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="Child">
      Child
      <p onClick={this.props.doSomething}>Click me</p>
           {this.props.a}
    </div>;
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  doSomething(){
   alert("Parent talks"); 
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="Parent">
      Parent
      {this.props.render({
        anythingToPassChildren:1, 
        doSomething: this.doSomething})}
    </div>;
  }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Parent render={
          props => <Child {...props} />
        }/>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

[Example at codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqadXX?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to do this.

You can pass children as props in parent.

**example 1** :

```
function Parent({ChildElement}){
   return <ChildElement propName={propValue} />
}

return <Parent ChildElement={ChildComponent}/>
```

Pass children as Function

**example 2** :

```
function Parent({children}){
   return children({className: "my_div"})
}

OR

function Parent({children}){
   let Child = children
   return <Child className='my_div' />
}

function Child(props){
  return <div {...props}></div>
}

export <Parent>{props => <Child {...props} />}</Parent>
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer is w.r.t. React v17.x...

Use the `children` as a function and pass props to it as a `render props` pattern, as below: -

```
 <ParentComponent {...anyAdditionalProps}>
   {
     (actualPropsToPass) => <ChildComponent>{children(actualPropsToPass)}</ChildComponent>
   }
 </ParentComponent>
```

Just make sure, the actual, to be projected content must be added like a function in render props pattern, to accommodate the argument passed as a `prop` within the children function.