# How to use React.cloneElement to pass a function property with a return object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, react-router

I'm using react-router which forces me to use `React.cloneElement` to pass down properties to my Children.  I can pass down objects and functions, but my issue is where one of my functions has a return object back up to the parent, which is always undefined.  The function triggers in the parent, but it doesn't receive the object I'm passing it from the child.

Here is a jsFiddle of the below example code if anyone wants to edit it https://jsfiddle.net/conor909/gqdfwg6p/

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

const App = React.createClass({

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.getChildrenWithProps()}
            </div>
        )
    },

    getChildrenWithProps() {
        return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                myFunction: this.myFunction
            });
        });
    },
    // NOTE:
    // the idea is that the variable 'newForm' should be sent back up to App, I can log out 'newForm' in the Child, but here in App, it is undefined.
    myFunction(newForm) {
        console.log(newForm); // => undefined object 
    }

});

const Child = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        myFunction: React.PropTypes.func,
        myForm: React.PropTypes.object
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="col-sm-12">
                <MyForm
                    changeForm={this.onChangeForm}
                    form={this.props.myForm} />
            </form>
        )
    },

    onChangeForm(formChanges) {
        let newForm = {
            ...this.props.myForm,
            ...formChanges
        }
        // console.log(newForm); => here my newForm object looks fine 
        this.props.myFunction(newForm);
    }
});

const MyForm = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        changeForm: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },

    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                 <Input onChange={this.onChangeForm}>
             </div>
        )
    },

    onChangeForm(value) {
        this.props.changeForm({ something: value });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is hard to follow because your function names don't match up. For instance `this.onSelectedOrigin` is undefined in `MyForm`

Comment: @azium Apologies, my mistake. I'v made edits to the naming on functions

Comment: Are you trying to pass a callback to the child? You're just passing on object to `myFunction` so it's hard to see how you were planning to communicate something back to the parent?

Comment: Yes, I'm simply passing an object to `myFunction` but the object is `undefined` when logging it out in the parent