# react redux assign data to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have searched around, all questions are something about [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

But my situation is different, 
I fill `App` with a initial data -- `nodes`, and  map `nodes` to a `TreeNode`list, and I want each `TreeNode` has the property of passed in `node`.

Pseudo code:

App.render:

```
{nodes.map(node => 
<TreeNode key={node.name} info={node} /> 
)}
```

TreeNode.render:

```
const { actions, nodes, info } = this.props 
return ( 
<a>{info.name}</a> 
);
```

Seems node not be passed in as info, log shows info is undefined.

```
warning.js?8a56:45 Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `info` was not specified in `TreeNode`. Check the render method of `Connect(TreeNode)`. 

TreeNode.js?10ab:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

below just a more complete code relate to this question(store and action is not much relation I think):

containers/App.js:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import TreeNode from '../containers/TreeNode';
import Home from '../containers/Home';
import * as NodeActions from '../actions/NodeActions'

export default class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    // this will update the nodes on state
    this.props.actions.getNodes();
  }

  render() {
    const { nodes } = this.props
    console.log(nodes)
    return (
      <div className="main-app-container">
        <Home />
        <div className="main-app-nav">Simple Redux Boilerplate</div>
        <div>
          {nodes.map(node =>
            <TreeNode key={node.name} info={node} />
          )}
        </div>

        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    nodes: state.opener.nodes
  };
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(NodeActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

containers/TreeNode.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import classNames from 'classnames/bind'
import * as NodeActions from '../actions/NodeActions'

class TreeNode extends Component {


  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
    if (this.state.open){
      this.actions.getNodes()
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { actions, nodes, info } = this.props

    if (nodes) {
      const children =<div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} />)}</div>
    } else {
      const children = <div>no open</div>
    }

    return (
      <div className={classNames('tree-node', { 'open':this.props.open})} onClick={ () => {this.handleClick()} }>
        <a>{info.name}</a>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TreeNode.propTypes = {
  info:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    open: state.open,
    info: state.info,
    nodes: state.nodes
  };
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(NodeActions, dispatch)
  };
}


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TreeNode);
```

reducers/TreeNodeReducer.js

```
import { OPEN_NODE, CLOSE_NODE, GET_NODES } from '../constants/NodeActionTypes';

const initialState = {
  open: false,
  nodes: [],
  info: {}
}


const testNodes = [
  {name:'t1',type:'t1'},
  {name:'t2',type:'t2'},
  {name:'t3',type:'t3'},
]


function getFileList() {
  return {
    nodes: testNodes
  }
}


export default function opener(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case OPEN_NODE:
    var {nodes} = getFileList()  
    return {
      ...state,
      open:true,
      nodes:nodes
    };
  case CLOSE_NODE:
    return {
      ...state,
      open:false
    };
  case GET_NODES:
    var {nodes} = getFileList()
    return {
      ...state,
      nodes:nodes
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

For complete code, can see my github https://github.com/eromoe/simple-redux-boilerplate

This error make me very confuse. The sulotion I see are a parent already have some children, then feed props to them by using `react.Children`, and them don't use redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looping on `nodes` values, you call `TreeNode` and give the property `info`: that is good!

But when your component is rendered, this function is called:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    open: state.open,
    info: state.info,
    nodes: state.nodes
  };
}
```

As you can see, the prop `info` will be overriden with the value in `state.info`. `state.info` value is `undefined` I think. So React warns you that `TreeNode` requires this value. This warning comes from your component configuration:

```
TreeNode.propTypes = {
  info:PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Why `state.info` is undefined? I think you doesn't call it as it should. You should call `state['reducerNameSavedWhenCreatingReduxStore`].info`to retreive`{}`.

You shouldn't fill `ThreeNode` through both `props` & `connect()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are rendering a Redux connected component from within a parent Redux connected component and trying to pass props into it as state.

Why does TreeNode.js need to be connected to Redux? Props/Actions should be passed uni-directionally with only the top level component connected to state and all child components being essentially dumb components.

TreeNode should look similar to this:

```
class TreeNode extends Component {


  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
    if (this.state.open){
      this.props.actions.getNodes();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { nodes, info } = this.props

    if (nodes) {
      const children =<div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} />)}</div>
    } else {
      const children = <div>no open</div>
    }

    return (
      <div className={classNames('tree-node', { 'open':this.props.open})} onClick={ () => {this.handleClick()} }>
        <a>{info.name}</a>
        {children}
        <div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} />)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TreeNode.propTypes = {
  info: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default class TreeNode;
```

and the parent component would render TreeNode like this, passing the props in to the component:

```
<div>
   {nodes.map(node =>
      <TreeNode key={node.name} info={node} actions={this.props.actions} />
   )}
</div>
```