# How to change react component's child property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have react component with a number of various children:

```
render() {
    let Tag = '${this.props.wrapper}';
    return (
        <Tag>
            {this.props.children}
        </Tag>
    );
}
```

When some event occured i need to change `className` property of a number of children. Is there any way to do this from parent component?

Comment: Possibly a [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children) where you can find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
render() {
  return React.createElement(
    this.props.wrapper,
    null,

    // Children
    React.cloneElement(
      this.props.children,
      {className: 'assignedChildClassname'}
    )
  );
}
```

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your parent component, you can pass classNames as props

```
<Child className={this.state.classes}/>
```

Your parent state will have classes that would be changed on click

Comment: not in this case. Children may contain their own initial className, which will be replaced with `this.state.classes`(it should be changed only in some cases).

Comment: in your child component u can use className={this.props.className + myextraClasses}