# React Global notification system

Tags: reactjs

I have installed `react-notification-system` which is working fine and producing notifications. I am trying to set it up so that I have a global container that holds the notifications so if the user navigates to a different view the notification doesn't dissapear.

My CONTAINER file is setup using the following

```
  render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
              <Header/>

               <section id="main">

                 <Menu/>

                { this.props.children }

                <NotificationSystem id="notificationSystem" ref="notificationSystem" />

                <Footer/>

              </section>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

What I am struggling with is how to reference `this._notificationSystem` from the child components(this.props.children)?

A notification can be added using the following from within the container file.

```
this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
        message: 'Notification message',
        level: 'success'
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32371612/780027) you can do something along the lines of:

```
createChildrenWithProp: function() {
  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
     (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
       addNotification: this._notificationSystem.addNotification.bind(this)
     })
    );

    return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
}
```

in the container file do this:

```
{ this.createChildrenWithProp() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have missed this piece from configuration documentation

```
...
componentDidMount: function() {
    this._notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
}
...
```

Actually, in the latest React versions this pratique is deprecated and you should use something like:

```
<NotificationSystem ref={(ns)=>{ this._notificationSystem = ns}} />
```

where you are assigning the _notificationSystem of this (your component) directly on component rendering.

In both cases you will able to access to this variable to call the NotificationService methods, like addNotification etc.