# Where can I find the API guide for this usage of passing props to children in React

Tags: reactjs

All:

Im pretty new to React-motion, when I read its source(Motion.js) there is one place like:

```
  render: function render() {
    var renderedChildren = this.props.children(this.state.currentStyle);
    return renderedChildren && _react2['default'].Children.only(renderedChildren);
  }
```

I get confused about this line:

```
var renderedChildren = this.props.children(this.state.currentStyle);
```

I wonder what does this line do, does it just give those style to children?
if so, where can I find the document for this usage in React website?

I also find one solution for passing props:

[How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

R they doing the same thing in diff ways?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is more about prop types while the question you reference to is about injecting props, so the two are totally not about the same things.

Answer (score 1):

It is because in this particular case, the only child that is passed is a function. You can see that, for example, `TransitionMotion` component [accepts a single child which is a function](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/blob/85ca75c6de9ed85937d1c95646b6044a66981eee/demos/demo7-water-ripples/Demo.jsx#L45), for example:

```
<TransitionMotion willLeave={this.willLeave} styles={styles}>
  {circles =>
    <div
      onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
      onTouchMove={this.handleTouchMove}
      className="demo7">
      {circles.map(({key, style: {opacity, scale, x, y}}) =>
        <div
          key={key}
          className="demo7-ball"
          style={{
            opacity: opacity,
            scale: scale,
            transform: `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0) scale(${scale})`,
            WebkitTransform: `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0) scale(${scale})`,
          }} />
      )}
    </div>
  }
</TransitionMotion>
```

and in its propTypes, [`children` has to be a function](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/blob/e48fdad6d82fda32f2d4e5b3d2f295e82f6c580b/src/TransitionMotion.js#L204).

But in official docs (and in a usual way), `children` are instances of `React.createElement`, represented by DOM-like syntax in JSX, and being reflected from [a plain-object](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html), because `React.createElement` returns a plain-object.

The case with react-motion is *very rare and advanced*, although you may want to use this approach at some point if you find it more suitable than simply passing children components in a classic way.

Comment: Made up [a short note](https://github.com/taxigy/til/blob/master/react/passing-custom-children.md) on that.

Comment: Thanks, so to understand this code, I have to base on its code usage example, put a function within { } between <Motion>? But I wonder why the children is not the <div> element? I thought the children should be the interpreted result from that function...

Comment: Ok, I get it. So the required type is determined by what inside the {}, is it correct?

Comment: Required type is simply to throw warnings. It doesn't really do anything above that. It checks if the prop's value is of a certain type, and does `console.warn` if assertion fails.

Comment: Usually, children are either DOM elements or components, written in square brackets notation in JSX. On a lower level, these are plain-objects. Just try to call `React.createElement` anywhere on the console and see the returned value. However, if you put a function (or a string, or a number) as the only direct child, the result will be different and similar to one described in my answer (as in case of function).