# React Router with Redux: Pass only necessary props down to child level routes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have an App component that is connected to a redux store:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { 
    todos: state.something
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

App is the root level component in my react router hierarchy and so receives all child routes as children:

```
export default(
  <Route component={App} path="/">
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route component={PageNotFound} path="*" />
  </Route>
);
```

I want to be able to pass the props that are passed in to `App` via `mapStateToProps` to child components. It seems the accepted way to do this is to use `cloneElement` to allow props to be passed to children ([How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)). So the code in the first snippet above:

```
<div>
  {props.children}
</div>
```

becomes:

```
<div>
  {React.cloneElement(props.children, { ...props }
</div>
```

I find this rather ugly because it means I am blindly passing all props from my connected app component in to my children route components.

Is this really the accepted way of doing this?

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps this is an approach that is used? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730619/unable-to-pass-redux-store-beyond-react-router/39300618#39300618

Comment: If you don't want all props "blindly" passed down, you could `connect` your `Home` or other components like you did with your `App` component and have a different `mapStateToProps` function in each.

Comment: @MarioTacke thanks. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what props were created in `mapStateToProps`, you can extract and pass further only them.

Also, it might be helpful, if you return a single prop with all necessary data from `mapStateToProps`, let's name it `componentState`:

```
function mapStateToProps({todos, somethingElse}) {
  return {
    componentState: { todos, somethingElse }
  }
}
```

Then later you can pass only this single prop down

```
<div>
  {React.cloneElement(props.children, { componentState: this.props.componentState }
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's a good approach. Ended up going with each route component being a connected container with a mapStateToProps.