# Adding a props to a node object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My current component is receiving a node as props from its parent.

Let's assume

```
myComponent.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

where icon will receive something like

```
<Icon src="...." description="..." />
```

Now inside my component I just need to add

{this.props.icon} to get that rendered.

What I need is to add a prop color="#f00" to that node, in a way that it results in

```
<Icon src="...." description="..." color="#f00"/>
```

And I need to do inside myComponent. Not sure what's the right syntax to do so.

Comment: Don't mean to be rude but...what is your question exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Comment: @erik-sn ' how do you add a prop to a node passed as a prop

Comment: @PraneshRavi I sort of agree, this is a duplicate, just more generic use case, so maybe better to keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render this instead:

```
React.cloneElement( this.props.icon, { color: "#f00" } );
```

---

Another option is to pass on the `Icon` component rather than an `Icon` instance so that you can [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) which takes a `props` parameter.