# If <notFound/> component get executed add class to <footer/>component . React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

If < notFound /> rout get executed (i.e : if not found page get rendered I want to add class to footer component.

Below is my index.jsx  render function

```
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="pageData">
                {this.props.children}
                // <notFound/> component will get rendered here
            </div>
            <Footer/>
            <LoginPopup />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Below is my routes.jsx

```
 import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import App from 'layout/app'
import Home from 'pages/home'
import MyWagers from 'containers/myWagersContainer'
import Wagers from 'containers/wagersContainer'
import NotFound from 'pages/notFound'

const ROUTES = (
<Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/wagers(/:trackCode)(/:raceNum)" component={Wagers} >
        <Route path="*" component={() => (<NotFound status = "404" />)}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/mywagers" component={MyWagers} />
    <Route path="*" name = "notFound" component={() => (<NotFound status =  "404" />)}/>
</Route> ) 
export default ROUTES
```

So  can we set something globally or can we get route name so we can add class in footer component as per < notFound / > component get rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback that you pass to this.props.children and then in `<NotFound />`

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.setFooterClass('myclass');
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.setFooterClass('');
}
```

in index.js:

```
 <NotFound setFooterClass={myClass => this.setState({ footerClass: myClass })} />
```

and

```
 <Footer className={this.state.footerClass} />
```

[Pass props to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Comment: I am not getting this.
If notfound route get executed how can we send callback to footer component