# Gatsby/React: Automatically replace all <img> elements that are nth-generation descendents of a certain <div> with <ReactIntense> elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby, children

## Goal:

Create a photo gallery that lets you zoom in on large images using `react-photo-gallery` and `react-intense`

#### Possibly relevant:

Gallery will be part of a website with Gatsby frontend, managed by Strapi CMS, and hosted on an Ubuntu 18.04 VPS, but currently I am doing the development on Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu)

#### Process I need help with:

Automatically find all `<img>` elements that are nth-generation descendents of a `<div>` with class name `.react-photo-gallery--gallery` and dynamically replace them with `<ReactIntense>` elements.

Example of the html that the `<Gallery>` tag generates:

```
<div class="react-photo-gallery--gallery">
  <div style="position: relative; height: 1976.9px;">
    <img style="style" src="src" width="width" height="height">
    <img style="style" src="src" width="width" height="height">
    <img style="style" src="src" width="width" height="height">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to replace each of those `<img>` elements with a `ReactIntense` tag automatically and set the `src` to what it was when it was an `img`, but I can't figure out how.

#### What I've tried

I have tried to use the recursive function I found below to wrap the gallery and replace its `img` descendants with `ReactIntense` elements, but I can't get it working. I've tried many other things too, and looked all over for relevant examples or documentation. The function below comes from [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523340/react-replace-child-component-in-props-children).

```
const RecursiveWrapper = props => {
    const wrappedChildren = React.Children.map(
        props.children,
        child => {
            const type = child.type === 'img' ? 'ReactIntense' : child.type
            if (child.props && child.props.children) {
                return React.cloneElement(
                    {
                        ...child,
                        type // substitute original type
                    },
                    {
                        ...child.props, // Wrap grandchildren too
                        children: (
                            <RecursiveWrapper>
                                {child.props.children}
                            </RecursiveWrapper>
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
            return child
        }
    );
    return (
        <>
          {wrappedChildren}
        </>
    )
}

(...)

<RecursiveWrapper>
  <Gallery photos={imageDicts} direction="column" columns={columns} />
</RecursiveWrapper>
```

The code above seems to do nothing, and I'm stuck.

Can anybody point me towards some relevant resources, or provide a solution?
Thanks in advance.