# Wrapping React components in other React components that mange behavior props.

Tags: reactjs

I found this code online and because I'm new to React wanted to know how to use it without getting this error.

> this.props.children is not a function

From what I gather its listing to the body scroll position and trying to pass it as props to any React children its wrapped around. Am I correct ?

If so why the above error when I use it like below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Nav from './nav';
import styles from '../../styles/header.scss';
import bgCover from '../../images/homeslider.jpg';
import Scroll from '../utils/scroll';

export default class Header extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <Scroll>
                <div id='header'>
                    <div className="container">
                        <img src={bgCover} id='bg-cover' alt="background-image" />
                        <div id="temp-text">HEADER</div>
                        <Nav />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Scroll>
        )
    }

}
```

This is the **scroll.js** file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Scroll extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { scrollTop: 0,
                   scrollLeft: 0 };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
      this.setState({ scrollTop: document.body.scrollTop,
                      scrollLeft: document.body.scrollLeft});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.state.scrollTop, this.state.scrollLeft)
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `this.props.children(..., ...)`? `this.props.children` returns the children components of the component.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, so in my example code why would I get the error its not a function ?

Comment: Because `this.props.children` is not a function?

Comment: Ok can you give me an example of how I would use it. As I'm not understanding your comments.

Comment: scroll.js is the react component I found online. I tried to use it in my example Header component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew mentions, `this.props.children` is not a function. In your render function, if you wanted to render the children components, then your render would be written something like this.

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

In your example, the code above would place this JSX block

```
       <div id='header'>
            <div className="container">
                <img src={bgCover} id='bg-cover' alt="background-image" />
                <div id="temp-text">HEADER</div>
                <Nav />
            </div>
        </div>
```

into your `Scroll` component, because they are the children (nested) components.

Now, it looks like you want to pass props to your children components. You can do this by adding accessing `React.Children`.

An nice example of passing a function as a prop to all children components [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children) :

```
doSomething: function(value) {
  console.log('doSomething called by child with value:', value);
}
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
 (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
   doSomething: this.doSomething
 })
);

return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks this makes a little more sense. Its the second part i'm after the passing a function as a prop to all children components. Does the clone add any overhead or is it just cloning a virtual element.

Comment: Realistically, theres basically no extra overhead if any at all. You can see in this test that compares cloneElement vs createElement here:
 https://jsperf.com/react-createelement-vs-react-cloneelement

Comment: I also just figured out in my example you can also do this. <Scroll>{ scrollTop =>
    <div id="temp-text">{scrollTop}</div>
   }
   </Scroll>

Comment: I didn't know you could just warp it all in curly braces and pass a fucntion directly in which is what the scroll.js demands. I guess that was my question. But you have explained a cleaner way. Thank you.