# How to access the props of the parent Route in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There is routing on **React-route**

```
render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={App}>
            <IndexRoute  component={Home} />
            <Route path='/products' component={Products} />
            <Route path='*' component={NoMatch} />
        </Route>

    </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Smart App component that is the container

```
class App extends Component {
render() {

    return (
        <div className='page-content'>
            <Sidebar />

            <Content>
                {this.props.children}  // ---> Here output content from child routes
            </Content>

        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Here is **Products** component from which I'm trying to get **props.products** from the **App** container. But the Products component does not see the container props App. I think this is because the **App** is two levels higher

```
export default class Products extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

loadProducts() {
    this.props.getProducts()
}

render() {
    console.log(this.props.products); // undefined

    return (
        <div>
           <h3>Products</h3>

        </div>
    )
}
}
```

In the container **App** there is **props.products** I checked in chrome-dev-tools. But how do you pass it to the **Products** component?

Comment: App is ot two levels higher but the direct parent. However if you are getting the prop in App component through redux state you can get the same in product component using mapStateToProps there

Comment: Alternatively, I think you can pass `props` to `this.props.children` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children).

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I think this is bad way for solve my issue ))

Comment: @saadq  Thunk you, I found solution with your link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)