# Passing states to this.props.children using Nested Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I agree there are multiple questions asked for the same. I did a lot of research for a few hours, however, I couldnt resolve this easy looking error. According to [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children?noredirect=1&lq=1) post, i understand the easy use of `React.cloneElement` and `React.Children`.

Following is my Parent Class:

```
class AboutPage extends React.Component {

constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
        details: "details"
    }
}
render() {

    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
        (child) => {
            React.cloneElement(child, {
                details: this.state.details
            })
        }
    );

    return (
        <div className="jumbotron">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>This application uses React, Redux, React Router and other libs for our EducationOne Project</p>
            <Link to="/about/Owner">
                <Button color="primary">test</Button>
            </Link>
            {childrenWithProps}
        </div>

    );
  }
}

AboutPage.PropTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Following is my child component:

```
const Owner = (props) => {
return (
    <div>Owner details: {props.details}</div>
  );
};
```

Instead of importing the child or parent, i nested the route in my routes.js to create a child for aboutPage:

```
export default (
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Login} />
    <Route path="home" component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="about" component={AboutPage}>
        <Route path="omkar" components={Omkar} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="courses" component={CoursesPage}>
        {/*<IndexRoute components={CourseDetailsAndList}/>*/}
    </Route>
</Route>
);
```

However, I dont see any error or any message in the console, nor the child component loaded when i click the button to load the child component.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `map` function. The callback arrow [function has block body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) with brackets and so you need to explicitly return your cloned element with the `return` keyword.

> In a concise body, only an expression is needed, and an implicit
>   return is attached. In a block body, you must use an explicit return
>   statement.

```
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    details: this.state.details
  });
});
```