# How to pass information to nested components in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have

```
<component1>
     <component2>
           <component3>
                 <component4>
```

(where component1 has a child component2, component2  has a child component3, component3 has a child component4 )

and say I want to pass something from component1 into component4 . Do I need to pass props down the chain? so component1 -> component2 -> component3 -> component4

?

**Please note:**
**these components are not in the same file. so in component1.js I refer to `<component2>` and in component2.js I refer to `<component3>` etc.**

Comment: Either that or use redux stores.

Comment: `control1`, `control2` etc. are those components?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi yeah modified question

Comment: so I need to use redux and actions and reducers just to pass some simple information? sigh..

Comment: @foreyez: No...

Comment: component1 cannot know anything about component4, so how is it supposed to pass something to it? You might have to rethink your architecture, but you are not providing enough information to offer any suggestion.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children

Answer (score 9):

You have 2 main options here:

1. Pass down the props.
2. Use the [`context` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

With `props` you also got 2 main options:

1. You can pass the props implicit

   ```
   <Parent>
     <ChildOne {...props}>
       <ChildTwo {...props}>
       </ChildTwo>
     </ChildOne>
   </Parent>
   ```

   **Running snippet for implicit props:**

   ```js
   const ChildTwo = props => (
     <div>{`Child two says: ${props.myProp}`}</div>
   );

   const ChildOne = props => (
     <div>
       <ChildTwo {...props} />
     </div>
   );

   const Parent = props => (
         <div>
           <ChildOne  {...props} />
         </div>
       );

   ReactDOM.render(<Parent myProp="hi there" />, document.getElementById('root'));
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
   <div id="root"></div>
   ```
2. Or do it explicit

   ```
   <Parent>
     <ChildOne propOne={propOne}>
       <ChildTwo propOne={propOne}>
       </ChildTwo>
     </ChildOne>
   </Parent>
   ```

   **Running snippet for explicit props:**

```js
const ChildTwo = (props) => (
  <div>{`Child two says: ${props.myProp}`}</div>
);

const ChildOne = props => (
  <div>
    <ChildTwo myProp={props.myProp} />
  </div>
);

const Parent = props => (
      <div>
        <ChildOne  myProp={props.myProp} />
      </div>
    );

ReactDOM.render(<Parent myProp="hi there" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

As for the context API,  you can skip levels and "grab" props from grandparents.
This is what [`react-redux` does behind the scenes](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html).

**Running example of the context API**:

```js
const ChildTwo = (props, context) => (
  <div>{`Child two says: ${context.myProp}`}</div>
);

ChildTwo.contextTypes = { myProp: React.PropTypes.string }

const ChildOne = props => (
  <div>
    <ChildTwo />
  </div>
);

class Parent extends React.Component {

  getChildContext() {
    const { myProp } = this.props;
    return { myProp };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildOne />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Parent.childContextTypes = {
  myProp: React.PropTypes.string
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent myProp="hi there" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

*Note that this example is using react v15, which the syntax for `React.PropTypes` is changed, Since react v16 `PropTypes` is no longer part of the `react` library and it was extracted to another library `prop-types`.*

**Also Note**, that the docs [advise against the usage of the context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context):

> If you aren’t an experienced React developer, don’t use context. There
>   is usually a better way to implement functionality just using props
>   and state.

Answer (score 2):

You can use React's inbuilt `Context API`, although I wouldn't suggest you rely too much on this because this either could get deprecated or be made into a full stable feature. As of now Facebook warns users with some points in their docs [**WARNING**](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context). Without that hiccup, the API is just wonderful and helps maintain neat code without having to send props all the way to the intended descendant.

[**CONTEXT API**](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

**COMPONENT 1**

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      yourProp: "someValue" // you can also add a function like yourProp: someFunc
    };
  }

  render() {
    <Component2 />
  }
}

Component1.childContextTypes = {
  yourProp: PropTypes.string
};
```

**COMPONENT 2**

```
class Component2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Component3 />
    );
  }
}
```

**COMPONENT 3**

```
class Component3 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Component4 />
    );
  }
}
```

**COMPONENT4**

```
class Component4 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.context.yourProp}      
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Component4.contextTypes = {
  yourProp: PropTypes.string
};
```

There are quite many strategies if you don't choose to use this.

- REDUX
- EVENT EMITTER
- PASSING PROPS ALL THE WAY TO THE DESCENDANT

Answer (score 0):

Yes with using just React you would need to pass down props through each component, even if the component doesn't use that prop. So in your example control2 & control3 don't care about the prop but need to pass it down. Below is what you would need to do.

```
<Control1 test={this.state.test}>
  <Control2 test={this.props.test}>
    <Control3 test={this.props.test}>
      <Control4 test={this.props.test} />
    </Control3>
  </Control2>
</Control1>
```

This can get cumbersome so this is a case where [redux](https://redux.js.org/) can help.

Comment: these components are not in the same file. so in component1.js I refer to <component2> ... and in component2.js I refer to <component3> etc.