# How to get parent props from descendent component?

Tags: reactjs

My structure looks like below. I need to read props of component1 from component5. How to make it? Thanks.

```
Component 1  

  |- Component 2

    |- Component 4

      |- Component 5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass information to nested components in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157223/how-to-pass-information-to-nested-components-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

You can use context in react or redux

Context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

And redux library: https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 1):

You have two main options here:

- Use the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- Use [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate?_sm_au_=iVVDs2s67s16Qtq6)

And the difference as per requirement you can choose [Context or Redux to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568073/react-context-vs-react-redux-when-should-i-use-each-one)