# Pass props to `children` without overriding explicitly set props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass down a prop from a parent component to all its `children`, but only if the prop isn't already set explicitly on the child--the user of the components should be able to override the pass-down behaviour easily.

This is similar to [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32370994/1267058), although with the difference that I want "fallback" rather than "override" behaviour: I want existing props on the children to take priority.

Concretely, what I want to implement is a set of components `Grid`, `Grid.Row`, `Grid.Column`, such that e.g.

```
<Grid size="big">  // A
  <Grid.Row>  // B
    <Grid.Column>  // C
      <Grid size="small">  // D
        <Grid.Column>  // E
          ...
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```

would pass on `size` from A to B to C, and from D to E. It's not passed on from C to D since we're explicitly providing our own `size` in the D element.

---

### Approaches

I can think of a few different ways to approach this.

#### Define a second "fallback prop"

With a second prop (say, `fallbackSize`), we could set this prop unconditionally with `React.cloneElement` the usual way. The child component then checks `size` first, and if undefined it falls back to `fallbackSize` (and then to whatever it would otherwise fall back to, if anything).

This strikes me as an *undesirable solution* since it introduces a new prop that doesn't actually represent anything, and merely serves to work around the lack of a nice way to provide a "fallback".

#### Inspect child for prop presence

I'm not sure if this is doable, but another "approach" would be to map with `React.Children.map` as usual, but somehow inspect the child element for whether the prop is present or not, and if it isn't, add it with `React.cloneElement` the usual way.

Compared to the previous solution, this feels a lot cleaner. However, it does require a reliable way of telling what props a rendered child already has, and I'm not sure offhand how one would do that (is it enough to just inspect `child.props.propName`?)

#### Rely on the new [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

React recently (as of mid-2018) introduced a new Context API that allows for managing state within a subtree of the React tree.  This seems like an excellent use case for it, so I would argue this is the way to go.

That is, the parent would become a Provider providing the passed-down prop's value in its context, and the children would become Consumers of the same context, falling back to this if a prop isn't passed explicitly.

There are a couple concerns here too, though: it adds some amount of complexity, and I'm not sure if "passing down a single prop so that children know of it automatically" is minor enough that the Context API would be overkill.  In fact, the Context API docs do provide the following notice:

> Don’t use context just to avoid passing props a few levels down. Stick to cases where the same data needs to be accessed in many components at multiple levels.

---

In essence, I'm wondering what the most sensible and idiomatic approach would be here.

Comment: Have you tried using `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` in children components ? It's automatically triggered when the component, well wrill receive props

Comment: @Henkan I'm not sure it'd necessarily trigger in this case? Like, it's not like the props of an existing element changes. I suppose I'm not completely sure how `React.cloneElement` interacts with lifecycle methods, though.

Comment: Well I think it would, if Grid is passing props, and get updated, children will also get updated and thus componentWillReceiveProps will be triggered I guess. Concerning `React.cloneElement`, I personnaly find it a bot overkill, like you are just checking property, so to me it would be better to just update the desired component instead of cloning it with new properties.

Comment: @Henkan I'm not changing the props of Grid. Grid is always passing size="big"; Grid.Row should ideally take on size="big" "by default" ("inheriting" it from Grid), but if I explicitly pass `<Grid.Row size="small">` I'd want that to override this default. Does that clarify?

Comment: That is to say, the JSX/prop values could be considered static; they won't change dynamically (so I don't see when either component would receive a prop change)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your second approach the code will be something like this

```
const renderedChildren = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
  if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
       size,
       ...child.props
  }
})
```

the size is the fallback size if the a size prop has been passed to the child element it will overide the value passed by the parent

hope that helped