# How to pass function from ReactJS HOC to child and call it here?

Tags: reactjs

I have a HOC

```
import React from 'react'

class Func extends React.Component  {

  addItem = () => {
    console.log('clicked')
  } 

  render(){

  const style = {
    background: 'lightgrey',
    margin: '1rem'
  }

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Func
```

an I have a HOC's child

```
import React from 'react'
import Func from './Func'

const AddButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <Func>
      <button onClick={props.addItem}>
       ok
      </button>
    </Func>
  )
}

export default AddButton
```

I'd like to pass that function (and maybe somewhat else) into child and call it here.

I see child have a nice grey background, so I think props are there.
But I see in react devtools any traces of function passed to it (`Props read-only Empty object`). So clicking does not lead to anything. ((

If background is already there, so where is a function?

Comment: Which method are you missing? `onClick` or the `addItem` one? Also, this doesn't look like a HoC, I just see a component which can render children.

Comment: @dubes yes, I mean `onClick` is not working.

Comment: This looks like it should work. I disagree with it being marked as duplicate, but I am not sure how I can ask them to undo it. Can you try by passing `() => console.log('I was clicked')`, perhaps your props.AddButton is getting lost. Alternatively, you can also look at the [render prop pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) for more explicit control

Comment: @dubes - no, still no luck. Anyway, thank U.

Comment: what do you pass to the AddButton prop when mounting the AddButton component (btw component and prop having the same name is a bit confusing ;))

Comment: @Benjamin yes, U are right, I'm passing `addItem` prop. Just edited. Still not work, props are empty. huh

Comment: it will not work like that. props.addItem is searched inside AddButton's props. This link was the link dubes originally suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children. It might look complicated but I'm afraid it's the only way to automatically pass props to your chilrden by wrapping them in your custom Func element