# Passing Props to Child component from Parent using cloneElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In the code below when the checkbox is checked in AddressWrapper the Ship To input in the AddressForm should be disabled. I can not figure out why AddressWrapper cloneElement is not passing it's state to the child. I have checked out many links about this issue and as far as I can tell this should work. This is the closest [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children) to this problem but it is using a callback from the child to the parent and I need a change in parent state to update the child. I could use a publish/subscribe to do it but I'm trying to do it the 'React' way.

```
class AddressForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "Joyce",
      disableInputs: props.billToSameAsShipTo
    };
    this.handleBillToSameAsShipToChanged = this.handleBillToSameAsShipToChanged.bind(
      this
    );
  }

  handleBillToSameAsShipToChanged() {
    this.setState({ billToSameAsShipTo: !this.state.billToSameAsShipTo });
  }

  handleFirstNameChanged(ev) {
    this.setState({ firstName: ev.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="form-row">
          <div className="col-6">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="First name"
              disabled={this.state.disableInputs}
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChange={this.handleFirstNameChanged.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class AddressFormWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      billToSameAsShipTo: true
    };
    this.handlebillToSameAsShipToChanged = this.handlebillToSameAsShipToChanged.bind(
      this
    );
  }

  handlebillToSameAsShipToChanged() {
    this.setState({ billToSameAsShipTo: !this.state.billToSameAsShipTo });
  }

  render() {
    const billToSameAsShipTo = () => {
      if (this.props.showSameAsShipTo === true) {
        return (
          <span style={{ fontSize: "10pt", marginLeft: "20px" }}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.billToSameAsShipTo}
              onChange={this.handlebillToSameAsShipToChanged}
            />
            &nbsp;
            <span>Same as Ship To</span>
          </span>
        );
      }
    };

    const childWithProp = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { ...this.state });
    });

    return (
      <span className="col-6">
        <h3>
          {this.props.title}
          {billToSameAsShipTo()}
        </h3>
        <span>{childWithProp}</span>
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const Checkout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div className="row">
        <AddressFormWrapper title="Ship To" showSameAsShipTo={false}>
          <span className="col-6">
            <AddressForm />
          </span>
        </AddressFormWrapper>

        <AddressFormWrapper title="Bill To" showSameAsShipTo={true}>
          <span className="col-6">
            <AddressForm />
          </span>
        </AddressFormWrapper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `AddressForm` has a method named `billToSameAsShipTo` but i don't see you ever use it

Comment: Yes - that was code from some earlier efforts - shouldn't be there.

Comment: I think that a [mcve] would really help here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jpondy/n5u2wwjg/228591/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AddressFormWrapper` you map over the children and passing props with `cloneElement()`.

As per the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap):

> Invokes a function on every immediate child contained within children...

But take a good look who are those (immediate) children of `AddressFormWrapper`:

```
<AddressFormWrapper title="Bill To" showSameAsShipTo={true}>
  <span className="col-6">
    <AddressForm />
  </span>
</AddressFormWrapper>
```

In this case its the `span` element and not `AddressForm`.

If you render it like this it will work as expected:

```
<AddressFormWrapper title="Bill To" showSameAsShipTo={true}>
    <AddressForm />
</AddressFormWrapper>
```

Another thing to watch out from, in `AddressForm` you are setting the state:

```
disableInputs: props.billToSameAsShipTo
```

This is inside the `constructor` and it will only run once. So it will get the initial value but won't get changed.
Either update it in [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) or better just use the props directly:

```
disabled={this.props.billToSameAsShipTo}
```

Here is a running example:

```js
class AddressForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "Joyce",
      disableInputs: props.billToSameAsShipTo
    };
    this.handleBillToSameAsShipToChanged = this.handleBillToSameAsShipToChanged.bind(
      this
    );
  }

  handleBillToSameAsShipToChanged() {
    this.setState({ billToSameAsShipTo: !this.state.billToSameAsShipTo });
  }

  handleFirstNameChanged(ev) {
    this.setState({ firstName: ev.target.value });
  }

  billToSameAsShipTo() {
    if (this.props.showSameAsShipTo === true) {
      return (
        <span style={{ fontSize: "10pt" }}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.billToSameAsShipTo}
            onChange={this.handleBillToSameAsShipToChanged}
          />&nbsp;<span>Same as Ship To</span>
        </span>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="form-row">
          <div className="col-6">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="First name"
              disabled={this.props.billToSameAsShipTo}
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChange={this.handleFirstNameChanged.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class AddressFormWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      billToSameAsShipTo: true
    };
    this.handlebillToSameAsShipToChanged = this.handlebillToSameAsShipToChanged.bind(
      this
    );
  }

  handlebillToSameAsShipToChanged() {
    this.setState({ billToSameAsShipTo: !this.state.billToSameAsShipTo });
  }

  render() {
    const billToSameAsShipTo = () => {
      if (this.props.showSameAsShipTo === true) {
        return (
          <span style={{ fontSize: "10pt", marginLeft: "20px" }}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.billToSameAsShipTo}
              onChange={this.handlebillToSameAsShipToChanged}
            />&nbsp;<span>Same as Ship To</span>
          </span>
        );
      }
    };

    const childWithProp = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { ...this.state });
    });

    return (
      <span className="col-6">
        <h3>
          {this.props.title}
          {billToSameAsShipTo()}
        </h3>
        <span>{childWithProp}</span>
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const Checkout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div className="row">
        <AddressFormWrapper title="Ship To" showSameAsShipTo={false}>
          <span className="col-6">
            <AddressForm />
          </span>
        </AddressFormWrapper>

        <AddressFormWrapper title="Bill To" showSameAsShipTo={true}>
          <AddressForm />
        </AddressFormWrapper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Checkout />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: Well done! I'm still trying to digest these React nuances (and reading skills). Appreciate the help.