# passing text box value to another React page in different page whereas shows in same page

Tags: reactjs

I have finding difficault to pass the value form one component to another component in React Js.
I have files like **App.js** and **Home.JS**

**App.js** have one input box and one h1 tag while typing on the input box the value will be displayed inside the h1 tag. I wants the same method whereas instead of displaying on the same page i want to display the same value in **Home.js** with React Router.

**Appp.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        name : "sivaprakash",
        age : 25
    }
  }
  update(e){
    this.setState({name: e.target.value})
  }
  render() {


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} width="50" height="50" className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        </header>
        <section>
          <h1>{this.state.name} - {this.state.age}</h1>
          <form>
              <input type="text" name="tx1" onChange={this.update.bind(this)} placeholder="Type Something..."/>
          </form>
          </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        name : "",

    }
  }

  render() {


    return (
      <div className="App">
          <h1>{this.state.name} </h1>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Please let me know if my question seems confusing.

Comment: where is your home component? please post

Comment: are you using redux in your application?

Comment: @Ashwamegh No, do we need Redux in this kind of process?

Comment: @Justcode i have updated my code now. have a look at plz.

Comment: Yeah, redux or any similar library can make it simpler for you to pass the data, or either you can use the React Context in your application. Since these components are not connected. So you can't pass the data as the props also

Comment: I would definitely not recommend using neither redux nor react context for this kind of simple operation. I'll write an answer with how I would do it using simple react component state.

Comment: @darksmurf am also eager to know that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to render `Home.js` in `App.js`.

```
import Home from './home_component_path'
```

ex: `import Home from './Home';`

Then render `Home` component bellow `form` section or wherever to wish to, and pass `App.js` state as props to `Home.js` like this in `App.js`

```
<Home user={this.state}/>
```

In `Home.js` component render passed props like this.
Instead of  `<h1>{this.state.name} </h1>` do this `<h1>{this.props.user.name} </h1>`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

as per your cod, Value getting printed in App.js itself but i need to navigate to Home.js and want to printed there in Home.js.

Answer (score 1):

In React this is usually solved by [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), meaning you keep the state in a parent component and pass the value (and, if you want to, a change handler) down to the child components showing the data.

Using React Router you could do something like this:

**Parent.js**:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    state = {
        name: "sivaprakash",
        age: 25
    };

    changeName = newName => this.setState({ name: newName });

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/app"
                           render={() =>
                               <App name={this.state.name}
                                    age={this.state.age}
                                    changeName={this.changeName} />
                           } />
                    <Route path="/home"
                           render={() =>
                               <Home name={this.state.name} />
                           } />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.js**:

```
class App extends Component {
    update(e) {
        this.props.changeName(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo}
                         width="50"
                         height="50"
                         className="App-logo"
                         alt="logo" />
                </header>
                <section>
                    <h1>{this.props.name} - {this.props.age}</h1>
                    <form>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="tx1"
                               onChange={this.update.bind(this)}
                               placeholder="Type Something..." />
                    </form>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Home.js**:

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>{this.props.name} </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as the correct solution ;)