# ReactJS add callback function to children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to attach a callback to a already created react component, is this possible?

This is my wrapper class, I want to call the `callbackToCall` from the existing children:

```
import React from 'react';
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    callbackToCall() {
        console.log("callback called.");
    }    

    render() {
        const {children} = this.props;
        // Here I want to attach the callback to call
        // E.g. children.props.callback = callbackToCall;
        return (
        <div>
            MyStuff
            {children};
        </div>
        ); 
    }
}
```

Child class, which does not have any callback to the container class:

```
import React from 'react';
class Child extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.props.callback}>Click me</button>
    }
}
```

This is the call of my component, here I don't know how to reference the callback:

```
<MyComponent>
    <Child /* Here I cannot set the callback callback={...callbackToCall}*/ />
</MyComponent>
```

Comment: This might be useful to you, especially the 2nd answer about React.Context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children

Comment: I am not sure I understood very well. By the way, if you create MyComponent as an HOC or render props? And the callback will be the prop you pass thorough

Comment: The wrapper component does not know which children it will get. This is done from outside the wrapper component itself. The unknown children component should be able to notify the wrapper about changes by calling some callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `MyComponent` is a wrapper that accepts the only child and supposed to provide `callback` prop to it, it should be:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        const child = React.cloneElement(
          React.Children.only(this.props.children),
          { callback: this.callbackToCall }
        );

        return (
          <div>
            MyStuff
            {child};
          </div>
        ); 
    }
}
```

Alternatively, `MyComponent` can be provided with a *component* instead of an *element* through a prop, like:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            MyStuff
            <this.props.component callback={this.callbackToCall}/>
            {this.props.children};
          </div>
        ); 
    }
}
```

This way `MyComponent` can additionally accept children for other purposes like `<MyComponent component={Child}>...</MyComponent>`.

Comment: I already thought about that but is it necessary to clone the children elements?

Comment: @KevinWallis Yes, because you're providing React *element* and not a *component* to MyComponent. If you need to modify props of existing element, you need to clone it. Another pattern that wouldn't require cloning is to make MyComponent accept a component, `<MyComponent component={Child}/>`. So you could return it like `<this.props.component callback={this.callbackToCall}/>` in MyComponent render. Both patterns are used in React world.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, could you please further describe the second approach on the answer above? :)