# How to use props of one reactjs file in another reactjs file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to transfer props from one file to another file.
I have file App.js which contains the following code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {graphql, QueryRenderer} from 'react-relay';
import environment from './environment';
import Toolbar from './components/Toolbar';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <select onChange={this.props.onSelectionChange} value = {this.props.text}>
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
        </select>
    );
  } 
}
```

and another file called map.js which looks like:

```
 import App from './App';

 class PublicMap extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: 'India'
        };
        this.handleText = this.handleText.bind(this);
      }

      handleText(event) {
       const value = event.target.value;
       this.setState({ text: value });
     }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <App text={this.state.text} onSelectionChange={this.handleText}/>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

But am getting no value in my map.js file from App.js file, Please help.
thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for this.

Comment: You code is working fine. Have you exported your `App.js` file?

Comment: I copypasta your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4kso0) and it's working as expected.

Comment: From code snippet, I guess you missed `export default App` in `App.js` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)