# useContext or call useEffect multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom useEffect hook to get current time every minute.

```
const useDateStatus = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setDate(() => new Date());
    }, 60000); 
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return date;
};
```

I need to a common component that when the date fall in the given time range, the component renders null, otherwise it will display the `date`.

```
const DateAlert = ({timeRanges, children}) => {
  const date = useDateStatus();

  if (!inRanges(date, timeRanges)) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Alert>
      <p>{date}</p>
      {children}
    </Alert>
  );
};
```

I also need another common component that don't need the date object.

```
const Display = ({timeRanges, children}) => {
  const date = useDateStatus();

  if (!inRanges(date, timeRanges)) {
    return null;
  }

  return children;
};
```

Should I create a context to contain the `date` in order to pass the `date` props and then make the `DateAlert`to use the context?

```
const context = React.createContext(new Date());
const DateContext = ({children}) => {
  const date = useDateStatus(new Date);
  return (
    <context.Provider value={date}>
      {children}
    </context.Provider>
  );
}
```

I need to get the `date` state, from [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children), I think it's good to use context to pass the `date` as props to children.

What's the difference between using the context to get the `date` or directly call `useDateStatus()` to get the date?

Or is there a better way to reduce the redundancy between `DateAlert` and `Display`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend making one component and then using that component for both like such:

```
const RenderIfInRange = ({timeRanges, children}) => {
  const date = useDateStatus();

  if (!inRanges(date, timeRanges)) {
    return null;
  }

  return children;
};
```

That becomes your `Display` component. Then:

```
const DateAlert = ({children}) => (
    <RenderIfInRange>
      <Alert>
        <p>{date}</p>
        {children}
      </Alert>
    </RenderIfInRange>
  );
```

I'd recommend looking into [Truefit's Bach](https://bach.truefit.io/docs/bachrecompose-renderif/). It allows you to use the HOC pattern for hooks and makes the code look a lot neater in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @Wilhelm, i suppose using this approach, `DateAlert` cannot get the `date` state from `RenderIfInRange`.

Comment: You can expose the date as a prop if you want to. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children for instructions/inspiration

Comment: I have looked into it before. I think the cloneElement seems weird and some comments said it doesn't work. That's why i'm looking into the context from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39401252/4157010

Comment: Well, you could still pass it via context I guess. It depends on your use case.