# How to update a property of a component which has been passed itself as a property

Tags: reactjs

Ok, I have a generic filters component which receives an index-filters component (set with properties in the index page) as a property. It will render it.

In the generic filters component, I have a method handleSingleFilter, which I need to pass to the index-filters component, but of course as the index-filters properties were set in the index page, it is not allowing me to update them.

In the index:

```
   <IndexFilters
      onSingleFilterChange={() => {
         return
      }}
   />
```

In the filters:

```
const { filters } = this.props
public handleSingleFilterChange = (filteredInfo: FilteredInfo) => {
    this.state = {
        filteredInfo
    }
}
public render() {
    filters.props.onSingleFilterChange = this.handleSingleFilterChange
    return (
        <div className={'filter-dropdown'}>
           {filters}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I get the following error:
filters.tsx:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'onSingleFilterChange' of object '#'

Is there a way to make the property writable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question which is

> How to update a property of a component which has been passed **itself as a property**

check [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

You can use `React.cloneElement()` here see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

something like this

```
const newFilters = React.cloneElement(
  this.props.filters,
  {onSingleFilterChange: this.handleSingleFilterChange},
);
return (
  <div className={'filter-dropdown'}>
    {newFilters}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up changing my logic so I could move the handleSingleFilterChange to the index, then no need to do anything hacky.

Answer (score -1):

if filters is not rendered yet then you can do like this

```
<div className={'filter-dropdown'}>
  <filters onSingleFilterChange = {this.handleSingleFilterChange}>
</div>
```

otherwise no need to rewrite props, you can write value directly to any attribute of an object

```
filters.onSingleFilterChange = this.handleSingleFilterChange
```

Comment: because filter is being passed as a props and props are read only so this is not the recommended way also fliter is a React element ( means it's already converted from JSX so you can't use it like JSX)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children

Comment: did you checked the link I gave you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children

Comment: and read the question carefully again  **itself as a property**

Comment: So component1 renders component2, passes itself as a property to it and component2 renders component1? It leads to recursion, no? Anyway it all looks weird