# How to pass state from parent to child in react?

Tags: reactjs

How do I pass a state attribute from parent to child? In the following implementation, the Dropdown component has a state "isActive" and I want to access it in the Button component to attach propper styling to it. The Dropdown has to generic as it is supposed to take different sorts of buttons.

```
<Dropdown items="...">
  <Button active ="false" />
</Dropdown>
```

Dropdwon.js

```
...

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
         isActive: true,
        }
    }

    render (){
        return (
               <div className={styles.toggle} onClick={(event) => this.showMenu(event)}>
                    {this.props.children} /* want to set active prop for the child button here */
                </div>
        );
} 

...
```

Comment: Is it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. Lift your `Dropdown` state and keep it in its parent component;
2. Use `useContext` hook;

The first approach would be better, but it may not be good for your application (I cannot know that). Let me make an example for both cases.

---

This is an example where I've lifted the `isActive` state to the parent component.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

    handleIsActiveChange = (newValue) => {
        setIsActive(newValue);
    }

    <Dropdown isActive={isActive} setIsActive={handleIsActiveChange}>
        <Button isActive={isActive} />
    </Dropdown>
}

const Dropdown = props => {
    // You can use `props.isActive` to know whether the dropdown is active or not.
    // You can use `props.handleIsActiveChange` to update the `isActive` state.
}

const Button = props => {
    // You can use `props.isActive` to know whether the dropdown is active or not.
}
```

---

Instead, this exploits the `useContext` API:

```
const dropdownContext = React.createContext(null);

const Dropdown = props => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

    return (
        <dropdownContext.Provider value={{ isActive }}>
            {props.children}
        </dropdownContext.Provider>
    );
}

const Button = props => {   
    const dropdownCtx = React.useContext(dropdownContext);

    // You can use `dropdownCtx.isActive` to know whether the dropdown is active or not.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the answer I linked, there might be another way of achieving this that I didn't see mentioned.

You can send a function as a children element of your dropdown which will take `isActive` as a variable :

```
<Dropdown items="...">
  {isActive => <Button active={isActive} />}
</Dropdown>
```

Then, is the render function, simply call the function and send your state value as a parameter :

```
render(){
    return (
        <div className={styles.toggle} onClick={(event) => this.showMenu(event)}>
            {this.props.children(this.state.isActive)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Dropdown >
  <Button isActive={this.state.isActive} />
</Dropdown>
```

In your button get it with `this.props.isActive`