# How to pass props from parent to child in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-component

I've been refactoring a small application that was initially within one file into it's own separate components. Currently I have a child component `UsersTable` that I am rendering within the parent `Users2`. I am passing some dummy data from the parent as props to the child but am getting the lovely `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

I am using react hooks and passing props with the spread operator in the parent:

```
<UsersTable {...columns} {...data} />
```

And the child is receiving that here:

```
    export const UsersTable = props => {
  const [usersState, setUsersState] = useState(props)

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsersState(props)
  }, [props])

  const renderUsers = () => {
    if (usersState) {
      return usersState.map(d => items(d))
    } else {
      return noData
    }
  }
```

As well as down in the return function here:

```
<ActionList columns={usersState}>{renderUsers}</ActionList>
```

I am specifically trying to figure out why the data prop (an array of objects), is returning undefined. Linking my sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/luka-content-access-extension-kqdl8?file=/src/components/UsersTable.tsx:282-571). I wondering if the issue is perhaps related to passing multiple separate props via spread operators.

Any help or advice around what I am trying to accomplish would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn’t be columns=columns? Can you share the data structure of columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this a good way to pass props to child component in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996121/is-this-a-good-way-to-pass-props-to-child-component-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a correct way to pass down props.

Props are passed as properties of an object and hence you need to define a name and value to it.

For ex, you need to write,

```
<UsersTable {...columns} {...data} />
```

as

```
<UsersTable columns={columns} data = {data} />
```

Now the UserTable component will get this props object,

```
props = { 
columns=the column data,
data = the data
}
```

To use this props, you can use destructuring

```
const {data, columns} = props;
```

or you can use the dot notation,
`props.column` & `props.data`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Rohan! Was able to take it from there, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass by attribute

```js
<UsersTable columns={...columns} data={...data} /> /*<-- Changes */

export const UsersTable = props => {
  const [usersState, setUsersState] = useState(props)

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsersState(props)
  }, [props])

  const renderUsers = () => {
    if (usersState) {
      return usersState.map(d => items(d))
    } else {
      return noData
    }
  }

<ActionList columns={usersState}>{renderUsers}</ActionList>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **User2** component, import UsersTable component need change from this:

```
<UsersTable {...columns} {...data} />
```

to this:

```
<UsersTable columns={columns} data={data} />
```

And in **UserTable** component you need to change:

```
const [usersState, setUsersState] = useState(props)
```

to:

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState(props.columns)
const [users, setUsers] = useState(props.data)
```

`renderUsers` will be:

```
  const renderUsers = () => {
    if (users) {
      return users.map(d => items(d))
    } else {
      return noData()
    }
  }
```

And last, import `ActionList` component like this:

```
<ActionList columns={columns}>{renderUsers()}</ActionList>
```

After that, `UsersTable` component will working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Parent Component:

```
<UsersTable columns={columns} data={data} />
```

See my github for an example of how to use hooks and props in a similar way:

https://github.com/RyanJMorris11/helloReactHooks/blob/master/src/components/userList.js