# Retrieve props given to routes from components in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React app, I use  component to wrap the authentication required routes. As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32371612/8810941) answer, I assigned `userInfo` as a `user` prop to each and every child as follows.

```js
const RequireAuth = props => {

    const [userInfo,setUserInfo] = useState([])

    useEffect( () => {
            Axios.get('/users/me').then(res => {
                    setUserInfo(res.data)
                    console.log(userInfo)
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
            })
        }
    })

    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(props.children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, { user: userInfo })
      );

    return isAuth  ? (
            <div>
            {childrenWithProps}
        </div>
        ) : 
       (<ClipLoader
        size={120}
        color={"#123abc"}
        loading={loading}
      />
        )
};

export default withRouter(RequireAuth)
```

I wrap the auth required routes with `RequireAuth` as follows in `App.js`.

```js
<RequireAuth>
    <Route exact path="/courses"  component={Courses}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/courses/:courseId" component={Course}></Route>
</RequireAuth>
```

My question is: How can I access `user` in `Course` component?

Comment: Inside **Course** Component `props.user`?

Comment: Instead of managing `user` with state inside `RequireAuth`, you should go with Redux to do that. After that, a simple connect from `Course` to store will give you `user` info. You can access it in `Course` props.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass user info like this:

```
<Route exact path="/courses/:courseId"
    render={() => <Course user={this.state.user} />}
/>
```