# How to pass React Component prop to child function using {children}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I'm new to React so this may be something obvious but I can't pass through a prop to a function that creates Components from its parent.

I can pass props to child components, but the same doesn't work for functions.

I have `<Subscription>` which I can pass through arguments like so, from its parent `post`:

```js
<Subscription auth={auth} stripeAmount={post.amount} stripePlanId={post.planid}/>
```

This creates a Stripe subscription.  I want to limit the subscription to subscribe to the `stripePlanId` which I do so via:

```js
class Subscription extends React.Component {

  // https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom
  componentDidMount() {
    this.stripeCheckout = window.StripeCheckout.configure({
      ...etc...
      email: this.props.auth.email,
    })
  }

  newSubscription = () => {
    var stripePlanId = this.props.stripePlanId;
    this.stripeCheckout.open({
      amount: this.props.stripeAmount, // in cents
      description: this.props.stripePlanId,
      token: function(token){
        createSubscription(token, stripePlanId)
      }
    })
  }

 ..etc..
```

This works great.  But now to pass through the stripePlanId I can't find out how to pass the `stripePlanId` through since it renders via a function - this `{children}` argument seems to only pass in the function, and attempting to add arguments causes errors that they are not functions it expects to act upon the arguments passed:

```js
const FireflySubscription = ({children}) => (
  <FirebaseAuth>
    { ({isLoading, error, auth}) => {
      if (error || isLoading || !auth) {
        //it pushes these arguments to the parent function
        return children({ 
          error,
          isLoading,
          subscription: null,
        })
      }

      // the issue - how to populate this?
      const stripePlanId = ""  

      // when working this should return the subscription for only this planId
      if (stripePlanId) {
        return <FirestoreCollection
        path="subscriptions"
        filter={[['createdBy', '==', auth.uid], ['stripePlanId','==', stripePlanId]]}
      >
        { ({error, isLoading, data}) => {
          return children({
            error,
            isLoading,
            subscription: data.length > 0 ? data : null,
          })
        }}
      </FirestoreCollection>

      }

      return <FirestoreCollection
        path="subscriptions"
        filter={['createdBy', '==', auth.uid]}
      >
        { ({error, isLoading, data}) => {
          return children({
            error,
            isLoading,
            subscription: data.length > 0 ? data : null,
          })
        }}
      </FirestoreCollection>

    }}
  </FirebaseAuth>
)

export default FireflySubscription
```

I have tried to pass it through with another method, but the "scope" does not pass through:

```js
getPostSubscriptions = stripePlanId => {
    return <FireflySubscription>
// it gets these arguments from FireflySubscription function above
    { ({error, isLoading, subscription}) => { 
      if (error) {
        return <Error error={error} />
      }

      if (isLoading) {
        return <p>loading...</p>
      }

      if (!subscription) {
        return <div>
          <p><strong>Subscribe to get paid features</strong></p>
          ..etc...
        </div>
      }

      ..etc...

    }}
  </FireflySubscription>
  }

  render() {
    return this.getPostSubscriptions(this.props.stripePlanId)
  }
}
```

Any clue most appreciated!  The original code I'm adapting is from https://github.com/sampl/firefly if that helps.

Comment: Sorry I do not see how that helps :)

Comment: I think this post might help you [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the repository that you refer, its seems like you are rendering `FireflySubscription` from within Subscription component like

```
class Subscription extends React.Component {
    // other code here

    render() {
       return (
           <FireflySubscription>
               { ({error, isLoading, subscription}) => {
                   /*Some components here*/
               }}
           </FireflySubscription>
       )
    }
}
```

---

Considering the above, the simplest solution for you is to pass on the `stripePlanId` as a prop to `FireflySubscription`  component and receive it inside the component along with children

Now that `stripePlanId` is calculated inside `Subscription` component, it can easily be passed to the children of `FireflySubscription` directly from parent without worrying about it being routed through FireflySubscription

So the solution would look like

```
class Subscription extends React.Component {
    // other code here

    render() {
       return (
           <FireflySubscription stripePlanId={this.props.stripePlanId}>
               { ({error, isLoading, subscription}) => {
                   // stripePlanId can be passed on to any children here using this.props.stripePlanId directly
                   /*Some components here*/
               }}
           </FireflySubscription>
       )
    }
}
```

Now in FireflySubscription, you will use it as

```
const FireflySubscription = ({children, stripePlanId}) => (
  <FirebaseAuth>
    { ({isLoading, error, auth}) => {
      if (error || isLoading || !auth) {
        //it pushes these arguments to the parent function
        return children({ 
          error,
          isLoading,
          subscription: null,
        })
      }

      if (stripePlanId) {
        return <FirestoreCollection
        path="subscriptions"
        filter={[['createdBy', '==', auth.uid], ['stripePlanId','==', stripePlanId]]}
      >
        { ({error, isLoading, data}) => {
          return children({
            error,
            isLoading,
            subscription: data.length > 0 ? data : null,
          })
        }}
      </FirestoreCollection>

      }

      return <FirestoreCollection
        path="subscriptions"
        filter={['createdBy', '==', auth.uid]}
      >
        { ({error, isLoading, data}) => {
          return children({
            error,
            isLoading,
            subscription: data.length > 0 ? data : null,
          })
        }}
      </FirestoreCollection>

    }}
  </FirebaseAuth>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

> The term “render prop” refers to a technique for sharing code between React components using a prop whose value is a function.
>
> A component with a render prop takes a function that returns a React element and calls it instead of implementing its own render logic.

**ParentPost Component:**

```js
const ParentPost = () => {
    <Subscription auth={auth} stripeAmount={post.amount} stripePlanId={post.planid}>
        {(stripePlanId) => <FireflySubscription stripePlanId={stripePlanId}/>}
    </Subscription>
};
```

**Subscription Component:** In your render method, pass `stripePlanId` as prop to the `children`

```js
class Subscription extends React.Component {
  // https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom
  componentDidMount() {
    this.stripeCheckout = window.StripeCheckout.configure({
      // ...etc...
      email: this.props.auth.email
    });
  }

  newSubscription = () => {
    var stripePlanId = this.props.stripePlanId;
    this.stripeCheckout.open({
      amount: this.props.stripeAmount, // in cents
      description: this.props.stripePlanId,
      token: function(token) {
        createSubscription(token, stripePlanId);
      }
    });
  };
  
  render() {
      <div>
          ...
          {this.props.children(this.props.stripePlanId)}
          ...
      </div>
  }
}
```

**FireflySubscription Component:** In here, receive the `stripePlanId` from the parent like this:.

```js
const FireflySubscription = ({children, stripePlanId}) => (
    <FirebaseAuth>
        {({isLoading, error, auth}) => {
            if (error || isLoading || !auth) {
                //it pushes these arguments to the parent function
                return children({
                    error,
                    isLoading,
                    subscription: null,
                })
            }

            
            //const stripePlanId = stripePlanIdFromParent; // dont need this as we are destructuring from props

            // when working this should return the subscription for only this planId
            if (stripePlanId) {
            ...
```