# How to pass comp A variable to prop.children which in turn are the result of an array.map within the comp A

Tags: reactjs

An example will explain better then I can ever formulate it

In below code, how to pass the index to Child when Child is passed in as a prop

```
const ComponentA = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { data.map((item,index) => {
          return (
            <Child index={index} />
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

So my component A would look like this, and I want to pass the index to (each of) the children

```
const ComponentA = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { data.map((item,index) => {
          return (
            {props.children}
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

thanks

Comment: What? They're *both* component a. Give a less abstract example.

Comment: You could use React.cloneElement to pass aditionally props to the child component. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

Answer (score 0):

Use `React.cloneElement`:

```
return <div>{React.cloneElement(props.children, { index: index })}<\div>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

[How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)