# Javascript | Why it works twice in the beginning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react navigation 5. I want to redirect with Token. But the function works twice and returns null in the first. What is the reason and solution?

```
export default function Router(){
    const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getToken();
    }, []);

    const getToken = async () => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        setToken(token);
    };

    console.log("token:") //console
    console.log(token)

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AppStack.Navigator>
                {
                    token=== null ?
                    //..
                }
            </AppStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

```
//output
token:
null
token:
eyJhbGci..
```

Two rounds at the beginning and showing null in the first round prevents the program from running.

Comment: You can't fix it because the code in the component will not run as you want if there are some async actions, just leave it as it is

Comment: When the token is set, the code anyway will go further and then will rerender (because of the state change) everything what it needs

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Alopwer. If it needs to rebuild, why doesn't it redirect when you see that the token is full? Null is acting according to him for seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the component is rendered 2 times, because of the `useEffect` hook. It acts as a `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and updates the state, after the async function is completed, and here the second rerender occurred.

In general, your implementation is good.

However, you can try separating/moving the authentication login (token fetching) in a separate component, something like that:

```
export default function Auth(props) {
    const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getToken();
    }, []);

    const getToken = async () => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        setToken(token);
    };

    return token ? props.children : '<div>Loading ...</div>' 
}

export default function Router(){
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AppStack.Navigator>
                // Your Routes definition here ...
            </AppStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
      <Auth>
          <Router />
      </Auth>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One last thing bro :D How do I access tokens in the router? (this.props.parent.token etc.)

Comment: It depends on your architecture. If you're using Redux, you can keep the token in the Store and reading it with `connect`. If not, you can keep the token via React Context API and accessing it everywhere you want in the nested child components. Please refer to this SO questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children

Comment: @irfan, the most simpler way would be to clone it as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102287/4312466

But if you need the token in a nested child component, i.e. App => Router => NestedComponent, it would be better to check Context (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39401252/4312466) or any other State management solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying @Jordan Enev. But this forwarding process was very complicated and messed up. While React navigation is very easy in v4 without any help, I still haven't found a solution in v5 despite your explanation. I'm using Mobx. I want to steer in the simplest way just :(

Comment: I don't have any experience with MobX, but looking in its documentation in the Auth component `getToken` you should update your MobX store with the token value. Later, where you need the token, let's say the Router, you should observe the MobX Store for the token value.

Comment: Yes but not working. Because i using first time RNF(function component). Ever so far using RNC(statefull component).

Comment: Please create a simple jsfiddle/codepen exampe - and will take a look of it.

Comment: Here's an example of MobX + stateless/functional component: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html#storing-observables-in-local-component-state

Answer (score 0):

Setting state is async in react, that's why first time when it is running it gives null because after running everything in the script, it resolve the async call. That's why second time you are getting the token.

See the execution order:

```
const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {         -->(2), after component mounts
  getToken();
 }, []);

 const getToken = async () => {        -->(3)
   const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token'); -->(6)
   setToken(token);                    -->(7)
  };

 console.log("token:") //console       -->(4)
 console.log(token)                    -->(5)

 return (                   --> this will execute first (1)
   <NavigationContainer>
     <AppStack.Navigator>
      {
       token=== null ?
                    //..
                }
      </AppStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>             
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Rohit Singh. What would you suggest for the solution?

Comment: Better generate the Token before and set it to the `localStorage` and when call `Router` use that Token here

Comment: You can try creating a Wrapper/Parent component, that will be responsible for token/authentication only, and when the token is fetched, then you will render the child components too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Jordan Enev. Is it possible to show a sample code?

Comment: @irfan, yes of course. I've created a sample for you. If you have any questions, feel free to ask above the answer! If helps you, please consider upvoting/accepting it.