# Access data from two parent containers - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an component that renders different types of fields called `Item`. `Item` may render a select box with a list of `Users` or a list of `Inventory`. I have two containers: one for `Users` and another for `Inventory`. I originally thought to nest my containers but that appears to freeze my react app. `Inventories` and `Users` containers are identical except that one container holds inventory items and the other holds users.

Here is the `Users` container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


 class UsersContainer extends Component{

   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       users: []
     }

   }

   componentDidMount(){
     //put api call here
     this.setState({users: [{id: 1, name: "Test Name", email: "test@yahoo.com"}, {id: 2, name: "John Doe", email: "johndoe@gmail.com"}, {id: 3, name: "Jane Doe", email: "janedoe@yahoo.com"}]})
   }


   render(){
     return(
       <div className="users-container">

          {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => (
               React.cloneElement(child, {...this.props, users: this.state.users })
           ))}

       </div>
     )
   }

 }
export default UsersContainer;
```

I originally tried to nest the containers but this causes React to freeze:

```
<UsersContainer>
    <InventoriesContainer>
        {this.props.items.map(i => (
            <Item name={i.name} />
        ))}
    </InventoriesContainer>
</UsersContainer>
```

Item looks something like this:

```
function elementUsesInvetory(inventories){
    //returns selectbox with list of inventory
}

function elementUsesUsers(users){
    //returns selectbox with list of users
}


function Item(props){
    render(){

        return(
            <>
               {elementUsesUsers(props.inventories)}
               {elementUsesInventory(props.users)}
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I provide the data from `UsersContainer` and `InventoriesContainer` to the `Item` component?

Comment: Can't you use a single function for creating a select box? Do they have to be separate?

Comment: In my implementation I only use one function but I created two in the question just to try and convey my goal easily. @mplusr

Comment: Why not to merge Users and Inventory containers to one component? Why do they need to be nested?

Comment: @KenBekov I could, I was just trying to reuse the code I already had since all the functionality I needed was already built in both of the containers.

Comment: If _Users_ and _Inventories_ are identical, then the _Users_ component will pass **users** prop to _Inventory_ and not to the _Items_ component. You will have to change the way you access it inside _Inventories_ and then pass it to _Items_ accordingly or don't nest them to avoid all this unnecessary complications @CannonMoyer

Comment: Why are you using .cloneElement?

Answer (score 0):

Merging them into one component would avoid a lot of confusion. If you still want to nest them, you might want to pass the props by prop-drilling or by using the context API. **React.cloneElement** isn't preferred for nested child components. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49726454/14259273)

You can pass down the data with the help of React's context API. The **UsersContainer** component holds the *Provider* and passes *users* down to **Inventories**

The **Inventories** will then pass on the *users* and *inventories* as props to the **Items** component. I'm not sure if you need separate functions for the select boxes but I've added them in the demo anyway.

```js
const MyContext = React.createContext();
class UsersContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //put api call here
    this.setState({
      users: [
        { id: 1, name: "Test Name", email: "test@yahoo.com" },
        { id: 2, name: "John Doe", email: "johndoe@gmail.com" },
        { id: 3, name: "Jane Doe", email: "janedoe@yahoo.com" }
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="users-container">
        <MyContext.Provider value={this.state.users}>
          {this.props.children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Inventories extends React.Component {
  static contextType = MyContext;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inventories: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //put api call here
    this.setState({
      inventories: [
        { id: 1, name: "Test Name", email: "test@yahoo.com" },
        { id: 2, name: "John Doe", email: "johndoe@gmail.com" },
        { id: 3, name: "Jane Doe", email: "janedoe@yahoo.com" }
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="inventory-container">
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
          return React.cloneElement(child, {
            ...this.props,
            users: this.context,
            inventories: this.state.inventories
          });
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Items(props) {
  function usersSelect(items) {
    return (
      <select>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <option key={"user"+item.id} value="{item.id}">
            {item.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }

  function inventoriesSelect(items) {
    return (
      <select>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <option key={item.id} value="{item.id}">
            {item.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>users</h2>
      {usersSelect(props.users)}
      <h2>inventories</h2>
      {inventoriesSelect(props.inventories)}
    </div>
  );
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <UsersContainer>
        <Inventories>
          <Items />
        </Inventories>
      </UsersContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I good approach would be to put the state in common between those components in a `level up` in the tree component.

So what  are you trying to do:

```
<UsersContainer>
   <InventoriesContainer>
       {this.props.items.map(i => (
            <Item name={i.name} />
        ))}
    </InventoriesContainer>
</UsersContainer>
```

Would be:

```
RealFatherComponent extends Component {

// state that Item will need will be set here
  render() {
    return (
      < UsersContainer **propsShared**  >
        <Item **propsShared** /> 
      </UsersContainer>
      < InventoriesContainer **propsShared** >
        <Item **propsShared** /> );
      </InventoriesContainer>
  }
}
```