# How to render react children as a <Children /> and not {children}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple component:

```
const Test = ({header}) => <View> <Header /> </View>`
```

and call it like so:

```
<Test header={<View> Test </View} />
```

but it fails saying:

> JSX element type 'Header' does not have any construct or call signatures

How do I fix this? I need to render it like `<Header />` so I can pass further props down to it

I don't want to render it like `{header}` this.

Comment: @AjeetShah because 1. it's a component so should be rendered like < /> and 2 I need to pass props into it

Comment: @RedBaron no it should not. the receiving component will render it as long as it is a `React.Node`.

Comment: I need to pass in a prop tho? how do I do that?

Comment: I cant do `{header(prop)}`

Comment: @EmileBergeron sort of yeh. but can that work with any prop? still getting the error: `objects not valid as react child` for some reason

Comment: I'd suggest you use [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), which is explained in the linked thread as well, and can be used with any prop.

Comment: `<Test header={(data) => <View>Test</View>} />` and within `Test`: `const Test = ({header}) => <View>{header(data)}</View>`

Comment: yeh this is what I had initially but it's saying objects are not valid as react children...

Comment: It's because you're trying to render something like `{data}` directly, instead of the actual information you'd like to render, like `{data.title}`.

Comment: ah I was being an idiot and not destructuring

Comment: thanks, feel free to answer and will mark as correct. up to you

Comment: If you can, you should select the [thread above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children) as the "duplicate" since none of the current answers below are new, complete, nor useful, and neither would I write an answer that's worthy of duplicating the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass props to your children have a look at the React API with the function [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

You can foreach your children using [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)

```
function Component({ children, ...props }) {
    const newChildren = React.Children.map(children, child => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { ...child.props, ...props });
    });
   return (
       <div>
          {newChildren}
       </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can make it like this:

```
const Test = ({children}) => <View> {children} </View>
```

and use it like this:

```
<Test>
  <Header/>
</Test>
```

For more read the docs [composition-vs-inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: I cant coz Header != header

Comment: sorry i updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

you can try to do this

```js
const Test = ({header})=>{
  
  return <View>
   {React.cloneElement(header, ObjectContainingPropsYouWantToPass)}
  </View>
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102287/10739602)

Comment: EXACTLY what i meant. i am just proving a point that calling `header` as `<Header/>` is useless

Answer (score -1):

Let me know if you are trying to achieve this

const Test = ({header: Header}) => `<View> <Header /> </View>`

Comment: Welcome.
It is in general more useful to add this type of suggestion as a comment to the question instead of an answer (which it clearly isn't). That likely explains the downvotes you are receiving.