# passing data between child and parent component in nested component react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, components, pass-data

[image]

I used a component as a child as follows, and in the parent component, ie ShowBodyQuestionsForArchive component, I used the child component as follows: {children}

in ShowBodyQuestionsForArchive component(parent) i have another componet As follows:

[image]

I want to change the data of ShowImage component in ShowComparetiveItemsForArchive component(child), which is displayed as {children}

Comment: Try giving it as props to the child. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children

Answer (score 0):

```
 const ShowComparativeQuestionForArchive = ({question, number, items}) => {
     changeShowImage(){
        //changedData
     }
       return(
          <ShowBodyQuestionForArchive question = {question} number = {number}> 
               <ShowComparativeItemsForArchive changeShowImage = {changeShowImage()} number = {number} items = {items} />
               {
                showImage ? <ShowImage {changedData} /> //example
               }
          <ShowBodyQuestionForArchive/>
       )
    }
```

Now call the prop (changeShowImage) in ShowComparativeItemsForArchive

Comment: Changeable state are defined in the ShowBodyQuestionForArchive component. Is there a way I can change the parent properties in this component when I use {children}?

Comment: React.Children i think this might help