# How to call parent function from children in composition?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create an `Input` component to be used to compose new form elements.

```
const Input = ({ value, children }) => {

    const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState();

    return <div className='input'>
        {children}
    </div>
};
```

And my `Text` component would be:

```
const Text = (props) => {
    return <Input {...props}>
        <input 
            type='text'
            value={/*how to bind to currentValue of Input*/}
            onChange={/*how to call Input's setCurrentValue here*/}
        />
    </Input>
}
```

I need to store `currentValue` state in parent, because I need to manage it for many different inputs.

Also I'm stuck at how to call parent's `setCurrentValue` on child's `onChange` method.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-joliot-fzcjq?file=/src/App.js)

**Update 2**:
[Real code from my repository](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-sunset-6h1gs?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: `onChange={(e) => setCurrentValue(e.target.value)}`. I suggest that instead of directly calling `setCurrentValue`, you create a function in the parent component that calls the `setCurrentValue`. You can bind that function to `onChange` event as: `onChange={handleInputChange}`

Comment: How? Can you please show me? Because in your solution I get `handleInputChange is not defined`.

Comment: Did you define `handleInputChange` function first? Can you create codesandbox demo and share the link?

Comment: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-rain-5057f?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Yousaf, I had no idea that the `children` can be called as a function.

Comment: only if you pass a function.

Comment: @Yousaf, I tried to use that solution, but I got stuck at `muiName`. I provided a demo of that. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions:

- `Context API`
- Pass props to children
- Use children as funciton & pass relevant

Send that reference somehow using any method you see fit.

My preference: **Composition** with function

```js
const Input = ({ value, children }) => {

    const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState();

    const handlChange = (e) => {
       setCurrentValue(e.target.value);
    };

    return <div className='input'>
        {children(handlChange)}
    </div>
};

const Text = (props) => {
    return <Input {...props}>
        { (handleChange) => (
           <input 
            type='text'
            onChange = ( handleChange }
           />
        ) }
    </Input>
}
```

Explanations:

- [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)
- https://victorofoegbu.com/notes/pass-props-to-react-children-faq

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this.

// pass props to children.

```
const Input = ({ value, children }) => {

const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState();

return <div className='input'>
        {React.cloneElement(child, {onChange: setCurrentValue, value: currentValue}))}
    </div>
};
```

// using props in childern.

```
const Text = (props) => {
return <Input {...props}>
        {
            ({onChange, value})=> (
                <input 
                   type='text'
                   value={value}
                   onChange={(e)=>onChange(e.target.value)}
                />
            )
        }
    </Input>
}
```