# React Child Inheritance

Tags: reactjs, parent

Should be simple, but for some reason, I cannot figure out this one. I just want a value defined in the Parent to be usable by the Child, but delivering the variable does not seem to work.

```
    function Parent(props) {
      const name='Jimmy';
      props.foo = name;
      return props.children;
    }
    
    function Child(props) {
      const result = props.foo;
      return <h1>hello, {result}</h1>
    }
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Parent>
            <Child foo={this.props} />
          </Parent>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: It is helpful to include information about what you have attempted in-order to solve the question

Answer (score 0):

> I just want a value defined by the Parent to be usable by the Child.

- You are setting the `foo` property of an object and then returning the `children` property. How will that other property `foo` be available in the returning context?
- `{this.props}` refers to the `props` of `App`, not `Parent`.

#### Solution:

When passing values or closures from parent to child component, we can use 3 options.

- *Context API*

  - Use when children can be deep down from parent component
- *Pass props to children*

  - Use for immediate parent-child context sharing
- *Composition*

  - Use children as function & pass the relevant object

This accommodated example follows **Composition**.

```js
function Parent(props) {
  const name='Jimmy';
  return props.children(name);
}

function Child(props) {
  const result = props.foo;
  return <h1>hello, {result}</h1>
}

export function App(props) {
  return (
      <div className="App">
          <Parent>
             {(name) => {
                return (
                   <Child foo={name} />
                )
            }}
          </Parent>
      </div>
  );
}
```

**Further readings:**

- [How to call parent function from children in composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68811795/how-to-call-parent-function-from-children-in-composition/68864126#68864126)
- [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)
- https://victorofoegbu.com/notes/pass-props-to-react-children-faq

Comment: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Kindly run this snippet in `https://playcode.io/react` and let me know the result. I only tested there. So, far, the context of this question and answer do not concern with export, imports, or anything else. Developers should accommodate as needed.