# Pass props to a child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react functional component in which I want to display an icon.

```
function Item(props) {
    return ({props.icon});
}
```

and I display it like this -

```
<Item icon={<FaIcon />} />
```

Is there a way to pass in props to the icon from the Item component?

Something like this -

```
function Item(props) {
    return ({props.icon(props: {})});
}
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to pass the component instead of the rendered element, `<Item icon={FaIcon} />` and let the `Item` render the icon with the right props.

Comment: Otherwise, you're essentially asking: [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Just render it like any other component

first you need to send the raw component as a prop

```
<Item icon={FaIcon} />
```

Then you render it like a component

```
function Item(props) {
    return (<props.icon /* Here goes the props */ /> );
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! But everywhere the icon is used, it is shown like this only - <Icon />. Why is it so?

Comment: It's not working I am getting this error - `Invalid value for prop 'icon' on <div> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM`

Comment: Oh, sorry, it works! I was messing up as I had not updated the other instances of the component

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `props.children` like this:

```js
function Item(props) {
    return (<>{ props.children }</>);
}

<Item>
   <FaIcon /* child props over here */ />
<Item>
```

But this only sets props from where component is called and not within the parent component `Item`.
If you exactly want to set props within `Item` component the best answer would be the same as what @pablo-henrique said:

```js
function Item(props) {
    return (<props.icon /* Here goes the props */ /> );
}

<Item icon={FaIcon} />
```