# Undefined error when passing props to children React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children) question to learn how to pass props to children. I'm getting an error in my own components, though.

Component 1, DataWrapper:

```
export default function DataWrapper(props) {
  return (
    <DashboardWrapper>
      {cloneElement(props.children, { test: "hello there" })}
    </DashboardWrapper>
  );
}
```

Component 2, Migration:

```
export default function Migration(props) {
  console.log("props.test");
  console.log(props.test);
  return (
    <DataWrapper>
      <div>hello</div>
    </DataWrapper>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to pass the `test` prop from `DataWrapper` to `Migration`. However, I'm getting `undefined` when running `console.log(props.test);`. Am I passing the `test` prop incorrectly? What must I do to successfully pass props to children?

Comment: that props.test is belong to Migration parameter

Comment: You have to pass it like this. 
<DashboardWrapper key={ value }>
 </DashboardWrapper>
Then in your child component, You'll get in props.

Comment: You cannot pass props from `DataWrapper` to `Migration` because `DataWrapper` is a child `Migration`. Props can only flow *down*. You are currently passing `test` to the `div` which is the child of `DataWrapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure suggests that you are including

```
<Migration>
  <DataWrapper>
    <DashboardWrapper>
      cloneElement()
    </DashboardWrapper>
  </DataWrapper>
</Migration>
```

so the outside `Migration` Object does not get any props from the DashboardWrapper function cloneElement().

If your structure is different, try to elaborate the complete structure in your question.