# Pass prop from parent to child in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following page:

```
import ParentComponent from '../components/ParentComponent';
import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent';

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <ParentComponent color="white">
      <ChildComponent />
    </ParentComponent>
  );

}

export default Page;
```

Is there a way to access the color prop on the `ParentComponent` from inside the `ChildComponent` so I can manipulate some things based on if it's set to 'white'?

I haven't tried anything yet, please help!

Comment: You can use [states](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) or even global states ([context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [redux](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) ) to pass down the values to child components

Answer (score 1):

You can use Context in React.
Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

[More information](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a state to store the color and pass it to both components?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ParentComponent from '../components/ParentComponent';
import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent';

const Page = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('white')
  return (
    <ParentComponent color={color}>
      <ChildComponent color={color} />
    </ParentComponent>
  );

}

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parent component you can clone your children and add a property to them like this:

```
  {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { color });
    }
  })}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6p9qfb?file=src%2FApp.js

More info: [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)