# How can I pass props to JSX reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To preface, I am working on this for an internship on a very large codebase in which I am not responsible for making design changes. If it were up to me, I would look for a better way to achieve this, but it's not. So I am requesting you guys don't suggest I change the entire implementation unless what I'm asking is completely impossible.

I have an object that looks something like:

```
const object = {
   option1: {
     url: "...",
     icon: <Icon1 />
   },
   option2: {
     url: "...",
     icon: <Icon2 />
   }
}
```

In the UI, it is being rendered as follows:

```
{
   Object.keys(object).map(( option, idx ) => {
     return (
       <Component>
          {
            option.icon
          }
       </Component>
     )
   })
}
```

I'm looking for a way to pass props to the `option.icon`? The icons are different. Is this possible?

Comment: This is like asking if you can change the output of calling a function `foo()` with different parameters; it just doesn't work out or make sense.

Comment: @kellys this comparison isn't relevant as [React elements could be cloned with more props](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32370994/1218980), which is another solution used when you have no control over the input (receiving a React node instead of a component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`option.icon` is the **result** of calling `<Icon>`. You need to pass them props when you write the JSX.

It's essentially the same as:

```
option1: {
  url: "...",
  icon: Icon1()
},
```

… and then deciding you want to have passed arguments to `Icon1()` later on. You can't when you only have the return value to work with.

If you want to pass props later, then you need to assign the component to `option.icon` instead so you can write the JSX at the time you want to pass the props.

```
const object = {
   option1: {
     url: "...",
     icon: Icon1
   },
   option2: {
     url: "...",
     icon: Icon2
   }
}

{
   Object.values(object).map(( option, idx ) => {
     const IconComponent = option.icon;

     return (
       <Component>
          <IconComponent propName={propValue} />
       </Component>
     )
   })
}
```