# How do you pass different props to different child components in a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, rerender

I'm trying to understand the rendering in ReactJS. I'm following this tutorial from YouTube, but I want a better grasp on the subject. The video explains that if you pass down the child component

```
<Child/>
```

Then it will trigger a render of the parent and the child.
However if you pass down

```
{props.children}
```

Then it will only update the parent, if there are no changes to the children. But what if I have a series of different children? What if I have 20 children or 100? And I want to pass a prop to a specific child? Say I want to pass down a prop to the 50th child (or any other). Then how would I go about in doing this?

Say that I want to pass down these constants, would the children only re-render if they receive a prop or would they all re-render?

```
const [childA, setChildA] = useState("In Child A")
const [childB, setChildB] = useState("In Child B")
```

I tried using the code from [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

```
{React.Children.map(props.children, function(child){
                   
                    if(React.isValidElement(child)){
    
                        let clone = React.cloneElement(child, {...props})
                        
                        return clone
                    }
```

But I'm not sure what I'm doing, I'm think I'm in the right path, but I'm not sure how to get what I'm looking for.

Parent component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ParentCount(props) {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    console.log("Parent render")


    return (
        <div>

            <button onClick={()=>setCount(v=>v+1)}>Parent Increase +1</button>

            Parent count is {count}

            Children count

           {React.Children.map(props.children, function(child){
               
                if(React.isValidElement(child)){

                    let clone = React.cloneElement(child, {...props})
                    
                    return clone
                }

            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ParentCount;
```

App component

```
function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ParentCount>
        <ChildCount></ChildCount>
        <ChildCount></ChildCount>
      </ParentCount>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function ChildCount(props) {

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

console.log("Child render")
return (
    <div>
         <button onClick={()=>setCount(v=>v+1)}>Child Increase +1</button>

        <div>Child count  is {count}</div>
    </div>
);
```

}

export default ChildCount;

Answer (score 0):

the meaning of the first lines you wrote is this:

if you pass a prop to a child component, react will only update that component for you. ex:

```
<ChildComponent prop1 = 'hi'>
```

if you add a whole new child component to your Component, react will update your parent too:

```
function ParentComponent () {
   const [update, setUpdate] = useState(0);

   let updateComponent = null;
   if (update === 1) {
      updateComponent = <UpdateComponent></UpdateComponent>;
   }
   return (
       <div>
          { updateComponent }
       </div>
   )
}
```

sorry for bad example