# Reactjs Component Composition

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm trying to use the **el** data inside the **Composition** Component.I'm trying like this :

```
const Game = ["Cricket", "Football", "Badminton"];
    const Test = (props) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {Game.map((el) => (
              <li key={Math.random()}>
                <span>{el}</span>
                {props.children}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    const Composition = () => {
      return (
        <Test>
          <div>{el}</div>
        </Test>
      );
    };

export default Composition
```

But it's give me an error. I can't understand how to do this. Is there any way to get the **el** data inside **Composition** Component from **Test** Component ? here is my app.js file :

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Composition from "./Components/Header/Composition";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Composition></Composition>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Working example:

```js
const Game = ["Cricket", "Football", "Badminton"];
    
const Test = (props) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {Game.map((el) => (
              <li key={Math.random()}>
                <span>{el}</span>
                {props.children({ el })}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    };

const MyDiv = ({ el }) => {
  return <div>{el}</div>
}
    
const Composition = () => {
  return (
    <Test>
      {({ el }) => <MyDiv el={el} />}
    </Test>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Composition />,
  document.querySelector('body')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see you using this `Composition` anywhere

Comment: I want to use the **Composition** Component in app.js file

Comment: You could just use other prop than children and pass the data as props.

Comment: you mean like ` {props.el}` in Test Component ? But in Composition Component how can i access this el data? could you please elaborate this with code?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misunderstood your question. The thing you are trying to do is impossible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Comment: no. it's impossible I thought so. I need to implement other way. However thanks for everything

Comment: Why is this impossible ? I have temporary added a working example to your post

Answer (score 0):

First you nedd to update your Test component like this,

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    const games = [
      { id: 1, value: 'Cricket' },
      { id: 2, value: 'Football' },
      { id: 3, value: 'Badminton' },
    ];
    
    function Test() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {games.map((el) => (
              <li key={el.id}>
                <span>{el.value}</span>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
       const Composition = () => {
      return (
        <Test />
      );
    };

export default Composition
```

And your Composition nee to updated lie this,

```
import Composition from "./Components/Header/Composition";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Composition />
    </>
  );
}
```

this will fix your issue.

Comment: You can use id parameter for not to generating random numbers. And you can use <></> tag for Fragment for effienty.And you dont need el params in the Composition component its already rendered in Test component

Comment: I am creating an e-commerce application. when I created the header element, a situation created where i need to use the **el**   parameter in the children component  similarly , I have mentioned in this question. I want to apply exact this approach if i add id in my array then I have to  change many things in my application that is painful