# Passing function props to children in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to use `handleChange` in the `<Tab/>` component but couldn't get it done.

```
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
setValue(newValue)
}
```

How can I access `onChange` prop on `<Tab/>` component?

```
<TabHeader value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
      <Tab label="Tab1" />
      <Tab label="Tab2" />
      <Tab label="Tab2" />
</TabHeader>
```

Here's my `<TabHeader/>` component:

```
function TabHeader(props) {
  const { children, value, onChange, ...other } = props

  return (
    <ul>
      {children} <--- Tab components
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: pass it down as prop

Comment: Using CloneElement maybe? React Doc say "Using cloneElement is uncommon and can lead to fragile code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [cloneElement](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/cloneElement)?

```js
function TabHeader(props) {
  const { children, onChange } = props;

  const childWithProps = Children.map(children, (child) =>
    isValidElement(child) ? cloneElement(child, { onChange }) : null
  );

  return <ul>{childWithProps}</ul>;
}
```

Working solution can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-dawn-h56von?file=/src/App.js:514-754

Ref: [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)